# The Schrödinger equation as an Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, schroedinger-equation, many-body, second-quantization

In section 1.2 on p. 14 in the book *Many-Particle Physics* by Gerald D. Mahan, he points out that the Schrödinger equation in the form

$$i\hbar\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}~=~\Big[-\frac{\hbar^2\nabla^2}{2m}+U(\textbf{r})\Big]\psi(\textbf{r},t)\tag{1.93}$$

can be obtained as the Euler-Lagrange equation corresponding to a Lagrangian density of the form

$$L~=~i\hbar\psi^*\dot{\psi}-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla\psi^*\cdot\nabla\psi-U(\textbf{r})\psi^*\psi.\tag{1.94}$$

I have a discomfort with this derivation. As far as I know a Lagrangian is a classical object. Is it justified in constructing a Lagrangian that has $\hbar$ built into it?

Comment: This really seems to be deriving a classical field equation which happens to look like the Schrödinger equation for a quantum particle. The interpretations are completely different.

Comment: Related : [The Lagrangian Density of the Schroedinger equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89002/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, one may think of this as a mathematical rather than physical procedure. In the end one is simply constructing a functional,

$$S = \int \mathrm dt \, L$$

whose extremisation, $\delta S = 0$ leads to the Schrodinger equation. However, Lagrangians containing $\hbar$ are not uncommon. In quantum field theory, one can construct effective actions from computing Feynman diagrams, which may have factors of $\hbar$, outside of natural units.

Answer (score 4):

1. As JamalS correctly points out in his [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/385346/2451):

   - [Quantum actions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_action) in QFT are allowed to have $\hbar$-dependence.
   - If we merely want a [stationary action principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action) for the [TDSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation), and view the action functional as just a mathematical tool without physical consequences beyond the [EL equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation), then the $\hbar$-dependence doesn't matter.
2. However, perhaps OP's discomfort with Mahan's TDSE derivation is spurred by the following deeper question:

   > How we can get the correct semiclassical limit$^1$ and loop expansion$^2$ of a second-quantized path integral$^3$
   > $$Z~=~\int\! {\cal D}\frac{\psi_2}{\sqrt{\hbar}}{\cal D}\frac{\psi_2^{\ast}}{\sqrt{\hbar}} ~\exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar} S\right),\tag{1}$$
   > if the Schroedinger action $S$ depends on $\hbar$, so that various parts of the actions $S$ scales/are suppressed inhomogeneously in the semiclassical limit $\hbar\to 0$?

   That's a good question. The answer is that there are implicit hidden $\hbar$-dependence, i.e. one should rescale the variables
   $$\psi~=~\frac{\psi_2}{\sqrt{\hbar}},\qquad m~=~\hbar m_2,\qquad U~=~\hbar U_2,\tag{2}$$
   to obtain a classical ($\hbar$-independent) action$^4$ $$\begin{align}
   S~=~&\int \! \mathrm{d}t ~\mathrm{d}^3r \left( i\hbar \psi^{\ast}\dot{\psi}-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} |\nabla\psi|^2 -U|\psi|^2  \right)\cr
   ~\stackrel{(2)}{=}~&\int \! \mathrm{d}t ~\mathrm{d}^3r \left( i \psi_2^{\ast}\dot{\psi}_2-\frac{1}{2m_2} |\nabla\psi_2|^2 -U_2|\psi_2|^2  \right)
   ,\end{align}\tag{3}$$
   and to restore a correction loop expansion.

--

$^1$ For the semiclassical limit, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/351072/2451) Phys.SE post.

$^2$ For the $\hbar$/loop-expansion, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/270428/2451) Phys.SE post.

$^3$ Here the subscript 2 refers to a properly normalized second-quantized formulation.

$^4$ Schwartz, section 22.1, p. 395, points out that the coupling constant $\frac{1}{m}$ has [negative mass dimension](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/481249/2451), and hence corresponds to a non-renormalizable coupling.