# Which transformations are canonical?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, coordinate-systems, phase-space, poisson-brackets

Which transformations are [canonical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Be aware that there exist various definitions of a **canonical transformation** (CT) in the literature:

1. Firstly, Refs. 1 and 2 define a **CT** as a transformation$^1$
   $$ (q^i,p_i)~~\mapsto~~ \left(Q^i(q,p,t),P_i(q,p,t)\right)\tag{1}$$
   [together with a choice of a Hamiltonian $H(q,p,t)$ and a Kamiltonian $K(Q,P,t)$; and where $t$ is the time parameter] that satisfies
   $$  (\sum_{i=1}^np_i\mathrm{d}q^i-H\mathrm{d}t)
   -(\sum_{i=1}^nP_i\mathrm{d}Q^i -K\mathrm{d}t)
   ~=~\mathrm{d}F\tag{2}$$
   for some generating function $F$.
2. Secondly, Wikipedia (October 2015) calls a transformation (1) [together with a choice of $H(q,p,t)$ and $K(Q,P,t)$] a [**CT**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation) if it transforms the Hamilton's eqs. into Kamilton's eqs. This is called a **canonoid transformation** in Ref. 3.
3. Thirdly, Ref. 3 calls a transformation (1) a **CT** if $\forall H(q,p,t) \exists K(Q,P,t)$ such that the transformation (1) transforms the Hamilton's eqs. into Kamilton's eqs.
4. Fourthly, some authors (e.g. Ref. 4) use the word **CT** as just another word for a [**symplectomorphism**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectomorphism) $f:M\to M$ [which may depend on a parameter $t$] on a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$, i.e.
   $$ f^{\ast}\omega=\omega.\tag{3}$$
   Here $\omega$ is the symplectic two-form, which in local Darboux/canonical coordinates reads $\omega= \sum_{i=1}^n\mathrm{d}p_i\wedge \mathrm{d}q^i$. A symplectomorphism preserves the [Poisson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket).
5. Fifthly, Ref. 1 defines an  **extended canonical transformation** (ECT) as a transformation (1) [together with a choice of $H(q,p,t)$ and $K(Q,P,t)$] that satisfies
   $$ \lambda(\sum_{i=1}^np_i\mathrm{d}q^i-H\mathrm{d}t)
   -(\sum_{i=1}^nP_i\mathrm{d}Q^i -K\mathrm{d}t)
   ~=~\mathrm{d}F \tag{4}$$
   for some parameter $\lambda\neq 0$ and for some generating function $F$.

Now let us discuss some of the relationships between the above five different definitions.

1. The first definition is an ECT with $\lambda=1$. An ECT satisfies the second definition, but *not* necessarily vice-versa, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127833/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89025/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. The first definition implies
   $$   \sum_{i=1}^n\mathrm{d}p_i\wedge \mathrm{d}q^i-\mathrm{d}H\wedge \mathrm{d}t 
   ~=~ \sum_{i=1}^n\mathrm{d}P_i \wedge \mathrm{d}Q^i -\mathrm{d}K\wedge \mathrm{d}t,\tag{5}  $$
   and is therefore a symplectomorphism (by forgetting about $H$ and $K$). Conversely, there may be global obstructions for a symplectomorphism to satisfy the first definition. However, a symplectomorphism sufficiently close to the identity map and defined within a single Darboux coordinate chart does satisfy the parts of the first definition that do not concern $H$ and $K$. See also e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/197538/2451).
3. An ECT is *not* necessarily a symplectomorphism. Counterexample:
   $$ Q~=~\lambda q, \qquad  P=p \qquad K~=~\lambda H,  \qquad F~=~0,\tag{6}$$
   where $\lambda\notin \{0,1\}$ is a constant different from zero and one, so
   that the Poisson bracket is *not* preserved
   $$ \{Q,P\}_{PB}~=~\lambda \{q,p\}_{PB}~\neq~\{q,p\}_{PB}~=~1. \tag{7}  $$

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics;* Chapter 9. See text under eq. (9.11).
2. L.D. Landau and E.M. Lifshitz, *Mechanics;* $\S45$. See text between eqs. (45.5-6).
3. J.V. Jose & E.J. Saletan, *Classical Dynamics: A Contemporary Approach,* 1998; Subsection 5.3.1, p. 233.
4. V.I. Arnold, *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics,* 2nd eds., 1989; See $\S$44E and footnote 76 on p. 241.

--

$^1$ Although Ref. 1 and Ref. 2 don't bother to mention this explicitly, it is implicitly assumed that the map (1) is a sufficiently smooth [bijection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection), e.g., a [diffeomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism) [which depends smoothly on the time parameter $t$]. Similar smoothness conditions are implicitly assumed about $H$, $K$, and $F$.