# A question about canonical transformation

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-formalism, mathematics, poisson-brackets

I have posted this question in [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/743643/a-problem-about-symplectic-manifolds-in-arnolds-book) before with no answer till now. It may be more suitable to post here.

There is a problem in [Arnold's Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=Pd8-s6rOt_cC&pg=PA216&lpg=PA216&dq=show+that+the+map+A+sending+is+canonical+if+and+only+if+the+poisson+brackets+of&source=bl&ots=uKsiyNBDGt&sig=DUUCH1z_QAU3sQpR9yONvInggu0&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ei=R7NCU6KrK4aSiQfLsYDIBw&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=show%20that%20the%20map%20A%20sending%20is%20canonical%20if%20and%20only%20if%20the%20poisson%20brackets%20of&f=false) which says that:

> Show that the map $A: \mathbb{R}^{2n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ sending $(p, q) \rightarrow (P(p,q), Q(p,q))$ is [canonical](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=Pd8-s6rOt_cC&pg=PA207&dq=a+map+is+called+canonical+if+it+has+as+an+integral+invariant+generally+transformation+each+of+the&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ei=aTBDU4CvC4LyiAf9poHQBA&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=a%20map%20is%20called%20canonical%20if%20it%20has%20as%20an%20integral%20invariant%20generally%20transformation%20each%20of%20the&f=false)(p206) if and only if the Poisson brakets of any two functions in the variables $(p,q)$ and $(P,Q)$ coincide:
>   $$
> (F,H)_{p,q} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p} \frac{\partial F}{\partial q} - \frac{\partial H}{\partial q} \frac{\partial F}{\partial p} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial P} \frac{\partial F}{\partial Q} - \frac{\partial H}{\partial Q} \frac{\partial F}{\partial P} = (F,H)_{P,Q}.
> $$

I cannot solve this problem and think about it as following:
From $(F,H)_{p,q} = (F,H)_{P,Q}$ I can induce that 
$$
\sum_i \det\left( \frac{\partial(P_j, P_k)}{\partial(p_i, q_i)} \right) = \sum_i \det\left( \frac{\partial(Q_j, Q_k)}{\partial(p_i, q_i)} \right) = 0,
\sum_i \det\left( \frac{\partial(P_j, Q_k)}{\partial(p_i, q_i)} \right) = \delta_{j,k},
$$
and
$$
\sum_i \det\left( \frac{\partial(p_j, p_k)}{\partial(P_i, Q_i)} \right) = \sum_i \det\left( \frac{\partial(q_j, q_k)}{\partial(P_i, Q_i)} \right) = 0,
\sum_i \det\left( \frac{\partial(p_j, q_k)}{\partial(P_i, Q_i)} \right) = \delta_{j,k}.
$$
But in the other hand, to induce $dP\wedge dQ = dp \wedge dq$ I need that 
$$
\sum_i \det\left( \frac{\partial(p_i, q_i)}{\partial(P_j, P_k)} \right) = \sum_i \det\left( \frac{\partial(p_i, q_i)} {\partial(Q_j, Q_k)} \right) = 0,
\sum_i \det\left( \frac{\partial(p_i, p_i)}{\partial(P_j, Q_k)} \right) = \delta_{j,k},
$$
or
$$
\sum_i \det\left( \frac{\partial(P_i, Q_i)}{\partial(p_j, p_k)} \right) = \sum_i \det\left( \frac{\partial(P_i, Q_i)}{\partial(q_j, q_k)} \right) = 0,
\sum_i \det\left( \frac{\partial(P_i, Q_i)}{\partial(p_j, q_k)} \right) = \delta_{j,k}.
$$
Is there something wrong in the above reasoning? Can you show me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. OP's sought-for proof becomes shorter if we first introduce some symplectic notation. Consider therefore a [symplectic manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold) $(M;\omega)$. In a local chart $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2n}$, the symplectic two-form reads
   $$ \tag{1} \omega~=~\frac{1}{2} \omega_{IJ}~\mathrm{d}x^I \wedge \mathrm{d}x^J ,$$
   and the corresponding Poisson bi-vector 
   $$ \tag{2} \pi~=~\frac{1}{2} \pi^{IJ}~\partial_I \wedge \partial_J, $$
   where 
   $$ \tag{3}  \omega_{IJ} ~\pi^{JK}~=~\delta_I^K. $$
   The Poisson bracket reads 
   $$\tag{4} \{f,g\}_{PB} ~=~ (\partial_I f) \pi^{IJ} (\partial_J g). $$
   See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/302288/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/201620/2451) Phys.SE posts.
2. In a local [Darboux chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem) $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2n}$, the symplectic two-form reads
   $$\tag{4} \omega~=~\frac{1}{2}(J^{-1})_{IK}~\mathrm{d}x^I \wedge \mathrm{d}x^K~=~-\frac{1}{2}J^{IK}~\mathrm{d}x^I \wedge \mathrm{d}x^K, $$ 
   and the corresponding Poisson bracket reads
   $$\tag{5} \{x^I,x^K\}_{PB}~=~J^{IK}, $$
   where
   $$\tag{6} J ~=~\begin{bmatrix} 0_n & I_n \cr -I_n & 0_n \end{bmatrix}, \qquad J^2~=~-I_{2n}.$$
3. Now let us return to OP's question with some hints. The definition of a canonical transformation$^1$ $\phi:M\to M$  given in Ref. 1 is equivalent to the notion of a [symplectomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectomorphism) 
   $$\tag{7} \phi^{\ast}\omega ~=~\omega.$$ 
   Let us choose a local Darboux neighboorhood. Let the Jacobi matrix for the symplectomorphism be 
   $$\tag{8} M^I{}_J ~:=~\frac{\partial \phi^I(x)}{\partial x^J}. $$
4. Show that the condition (7) implies that the matrix $M$ is a [symplectic matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_matrix) 
   $$\tag{9} M^t J^{-1} M~=~ J^{-1}, $$
   or equivalently,
   $$\tag{10} M J M^t~=~ J. $$
5. Show that the symplectic condition (10) is equivalent to the preservation of the Poisson bracket
   $$\tag{11} \{ \phi^I(x),\phi^J(x)\}_{PB}~=~\{x^I,x^J\}_{PB}. $$

References:

1. V.I. Arnold, *Mathematical methods of Classical Mechanics,* 2nd eds., 1989; p. 206.

--

$^1$ Note that different authors give different definitions of a [canonical transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105613/2451) Phys.SE post.