# Why closed in the definition of a symplectic structure?

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism, poisson-brackets

Why do we want the 2-form $\omega $ to be closed? What if it is not?

Comment: Have you read the [motivation section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold) in the Wikipedia article?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First some terminology:

1. A non-degenerate 2-form $\omega$ is called an [*almost symplectic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_symplectic_manifold) structure.
2. A closed 2-form $\omega$ is often called a [*presymplectic*](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/presymplectic+structure) structure.
3. If the 2-form $\omega$ is both non-degenerate and closed, it becomes a [*symplectic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold) structure.

In the non-degenerate case, the closedness condition
$$\mathrm{d}\omega~=~0\tag{C}$$
is *equivalent* to the [Jacobi identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_identity) (JI) for the corresponding [Poisson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket) (PB). In other words, conversely, a violation of the closedness condition (C) would mean a violation of the JI.

Moreover in the non-degenerate case, the closedness condition (C) (or equivalently, the JI) is the integrability condition that ensures the local existence of *Darboux coordinates* (aka. [*canonical coordinates*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_coordinates)), cf. [Darboux' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem). Conversely, the existence of Darboux coordinates in a local neighborhood $U$ implies the closedness condition (C) in that neighborhood.

For further information, see also e.g. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_geometry)pe[dia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold)$^1$; [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32738/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/88920/2451), and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/157633/13917) related SE posts; and links therein.

--

$^1$ [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold#Motivation) (August, 2015) has a concise section about motivations arising from Hamiltonian mechanics, cf. above comment by ACuriousMind. Wikipedia argues that
$$\mathrm{d}H(V_H)~\equiv~\omega(V_H,V_H)~=~0\qquad\text{and}\qquad 0~=~{\cal L}_{V_H}\omega~\equiv~i_{V_H}\mathrm{d}\omega.$$
Next assume that $\omega$ is non-degenerate. To complete Wikipedia's argument and deduce (pointwise) that $\omega$ is
(i) alternating and (ii) closed, note that the Hamiltonian vector field $V_H$ (differential $\mathrm{d}H$) needs to probe *all* directions in the tangent (cotangent) space of the point, respectively. This can be achieved by choosing the Hamiltonian generator $H$ in $2n$ different ways. $\Box$