# Is there any relation between Poisson Brackets and the Jacobian Matrix?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

The Poisson brackets for $u,v$ can be written as,

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial q} \frac{\partial v}{\partial p} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial p}\frac{\partial v}{\partial q}.
$$

We can write this as determinant of this matrix

$$
 \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial u}{\partial q} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial p} \\\frac{\partial v}{\partial q} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial p} \end{bmatrix} 
$$

Which is the Jacobian matrix.

Is there any relation between them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. For a 2-dimensional phase space, they are the same.
2. More generally, for a $2n$-dimensional symplectic manifold $(M;\omega)$ with symplectic two-form 
   $$\tag{1} \omega~=~\frac{1}{2} dz^I ~\omega_{IJ} \wedge dz^J, \qquad \omega_{IJ}~=~-\omega_{JI}, $$
   the Poisson bracket is given by
   $$ \tag{2} \{f,g\}_{PB}~=~\frac{\partial f}{\partial z^I}\pi^{IJ} \frac{\partial g}{\partial z^J}, \qquad \pi^{IJ} ~:=~(\omega^{-1})^{IJ} . $$
   See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/302288/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/201620/2451) Phys.SE posts.
3. The canonical volume form on $(M;\omega)$ 
   $$\tag{3} \Omega~=~\omega^n~=~\rho~ dz^1\wedge \ldots \wedge dz^{2n},$$
   is the $n$'th exterior power of the symplectic two-form $\omega$, with volume density 
   $$\tag{4} \rho~=~{\rm Pf}(\omega_{IJ}) $$
   given by the [Pfaffian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian), which is a square root of the determinant. This is closely related to [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_%28Hamiltonian%29).