# Is the phase space a linear vector space?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

Is the phase space in classical mechanics a linear vector space (LVS)? If yes,, can we define operators, inner products in this space?

Edit: I have seen Liouville operator $\mathcal{L}$ in Classical mechanics defined as $$i\mathcal{L}\equiv \dot{q}\frac{\partial}{\partial q}+\dot{p}\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\tag{1}$$ which act on functions $f(q,p)$ of phase space variables $(q,p)$. One also defines inner product on phase space as $$(f,g)=\int dq\int dp f^*(q,p)g(q,p).\tag{2}$$ Using (2) one also proves the Hermiticity of $\mathcal{L}$ in Classical mechanics. For a link see [this](http://www.nyu.edu/classes/tuckerman/mol.dyn/lectures/postscript/lecture_9.ps).

Since this is analogous to the mathematical operators in a Linear vector space, I wonder whether a Phase space is a LVS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. A [phase space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space) is not necessarily a [linear vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) or an [affine space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space). More generally, it is a [Poisson manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_manifold) or a [symplectic manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold). It is often not possible to globally assign a linear or affine structure to a [manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold).
2. In [quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_%28physics%29), one often constructs a [Hilbert space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) ${\cal H}=L^2(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ as a [$L^2$-space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space) over a [measure space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_%28mathematics%29#measure_space) $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$. E.g. a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ comes equipped with a canonical volume form $\Omega=\omega^{\wedge n}$ (cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/211361/2451) Phys.SE post), and is hence a measure space. The Hilbert space ${\cal H}=L^2(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ is indeed a linear vector space. And it is possible to consider linear operators thereon.

Comment: 1. Can operators be defined on a Poisson manifold? 2. Is a LVS a special case of a manifold? For example, the link in the EDIT part defines Liouville operator in Classical mechanics.

Comment: 1. Well, for starters, operators do not need to be linear, cf. my Phys.SE answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/284534/2451). 2. A finite-dimensional linear vector space is a manifold.

Comment: @Qmechanic $L^2(M)$ needs a positive measure to be defined. On a generic manifold there is not. In the considered case however, if the Poisson structure over the $2n$-dimensional manifold $M$ is induced by a symplectic form $\omega$, there is the canonical measure $\mu = \omega \wedge \cdots (n \: times ) \wedge\cdots  \omega$. With this measure, the scalar product of $L^2(M)$ is  invariant under canonical transformations

Comment: @Valter Moretti: Good points. I updated the answer.