# Why do symplectic form need to be closed in classical mechanics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

Mathematical structure of classical mechanic is described by symplectic geometry which is a smooth manifold with a non-degenrate closed 2-form $\omega$.

I understand the requirement that $\omega$ should be non-degenrate and conservation of energy along flow lines implies $\omega$ to be a 2-form.
are not these conditions enough to deal with classical mechanics?

What is the physical (not mathematical) motivation for symplectic form to be closed?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/201620/2451