# Noether's theorem for first-order systems

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem, complex-systems

In a paper I'm reading (https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6120, equations 8-9) I've seen the following statement - given that $s$ is constant and $a,b$ are some dynamical variables obeying the following equations of motion:
$$\frac{d}{dt}a=b(s-ab), \qquad \frac{d}{dt}b=a(s-ab)\tag{1}$$
then, as this is going down the gradient of the function $$E(a,b)=\frac{1}{2}(s-ab)^2\tag{2}$$ and there's the scaling symmetry $$a\to\lambda a, \qquad b\to\lambda^{-1} b,\tag{3}$$ as per Noether's theorem the quantity $a^2-b^2$ is conserved. While it is easy to manually check that this is true, how is Noether's theorem used here? I haven't managed to formulate a Lagrangian or derive a useful first-order version of the theorem. Is there some generic Noether-analogous result for cases like these?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, OP is right: One can strictly speaking not apply [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) without an action formulation. (It is of course easy to verify that $a^2-b^2$ indeed is an [integral of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_motion#Integral_of_motion) (IOM), as OP already mentioned.)
2. Let us for fun try to cook up an action formulation.

   - First note that we can recast OP's EOMs (1) as Hamilton's equations
     $$ \dot{a}~=~\{a,H\}, \qquad \dot{b}~=~\{b,H\} \tag{A}$$
     with Hamiltonian
     $$H~=~\frac{1}{2}(b^2-a^2)\tag{B}$$
     and fundamental Poisson bracket
     $$ \{a,b\}~=~s-ab,\tag{C}$$
     cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/432664/2451) Phys.SE post.
   - It is no coincidence that the Hamiltonian $H$ is (a function of) OP's IOM, since for a 2D phase space, this is essentially unique.
   - The corresponding symplectic 2-form is
     $$ \omega~=~\frac{1}{s-ab}\mathrm{d}b\wedge \mathrm{d}a~=~\mathrm{d}\theta,\qquad \theta~=~-\ln|s-ab|\mathrm{d}\ln |a|, \tag{D}$$
     cf. e.g [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/302288/2451) Phys.SE post.
   - The corresponding Hamiltonian Lagrangian becomes
     $$ L_H~=~ -\frac{1}{a}\ln|s-ab|\dot{a} - \frac{1}{2}(b^2-a^2),\tag{E} $$
     cf. e.g [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/398159/2451) Phys.SE post.
   - It is straightforward to check that the corresponding Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations are OP's EOMs (1).
   - However, the OP's transformation (3) is *not* a symmetry of the action (E). This can essentially be traced back to the fact that the Hamiltonian $H$ is *not* invariant under OP's transformation (3).
   - Since $L_H$ has no explicit time dependence, Noether's theorem implies that $H$ is conserved.