# Find canonical transformation for $P$ given canonical transformation for $Q$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

I have just started to study canonical transformations and I am trying to solve this exercise. Given the following canonical transformation for $Q$,
$$ Q = q^{-2} $$
I have to find the corresponding canonical transformation for $P$. The determinant of the matrix
$$ M = \begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{2}{q^3} & 0 \\
\frac{\partial P}{\partial q} & \frac{\partial P}{\partial p}
\end{pmatrix} $$
has to be $1$, from which it follows that
$$ \frac{\partial P}{\partial p} = -\frac{q^3}{2} \iff P = -\frac{q^3p}{2}+k(q)$$
My question is: can I just take $k(q)=0$ to solve the problem or is there a unique canonical transformation given that $Q$? Are there any more conditions that $P$ needs to verify in order to be the requested canonical transformation?

Comment: Have you tried the method of generating functions for canonical transformations? It is not so easy to get the correct behaviour and so I really only trust answers going via that route because it is simple.

Comment: What's holding you back? What's spooking you? you preserved the phase-space volume, didn't you?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: The answer depends on the context.

Examples:

1. If we assume that a [canonical transformation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105613/2451) here means a [symplectomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectomorphism), then indeed OP's method is correct: the [determinant of the Jacobian is 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/242091/11127), and it is easy to check that OP's solution is a symplectomorphism. We should keep the "integration constant" $k(q)$, which may be determined by possible further conditions.
2. If $q\to Q=q^{-2}$ is viewed as a point transformation of the base manifold $M$ of a cotangent bundle $T^{\ast}M$, then the [momentum transforms as components of a covector](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/176555/2451)
   $$ p~=~\frac{\partial Q}{\partial q}P~=~-\frac{2}{q^3}P,$$
   i.e. $k(q)=0$.