# Why does a point transformation in configuration space imply that $P = \frac{\partial q}{\partial Q} p$ in phase space?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

## What the book demonstrates

In *No-Nonsense Classical Mechanics*, the author spends some time discussing how point transformations in configuration space correspond with canonical transformations in phase space:

> [image]

Specifically, the author demonstrates via [this proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S8u3.png) that a point transformation $q \mapsto Q = Q(q)$ implies that $p \mapsto P = \frac{\partial q}{\partial Q} p$.

## How is this not a counter-example?

I don't doubt the proof, but I'm having trouble understanding this intuitively.  For example, let us suppose we're in the context of a falling ball, where we can [demonstrate via the Lagrangian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD4gc.png) that $p = m \dot{q}$.  It seems to me that if $\dot{q} \mapsto \frac{\partial Q}{\partial q} \dot{q}$, then $p = m \dot{q}$ will then get mapped to

$$
P = m \left( \frac{\partial Q}{\partial q} \dot{q} \right) = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial q} \left( m \dot{q} \right) = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial q} p
$$

and of course this contradicts the idea that $p \mapsto P = \frac{\partial q}{\partial Q} p$. What is wrong with my reasoning?

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: $p=m\dot{q}$ and $P=m\dot{Q}$ are typically not both true.

Perhaps an example is in order.

- *Example:* Consider a coordinate scaling $$Q~=~ \lambda q,$$ where $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$ is a non-zero constant. Consider  the Lagrangian $$L~=~\frac{m}{2}\dot{q}^2-V(q)~=~\frac{m}{2\lambda^2}\dot{Q}^2-V(Q/\lambda).$$
  Then $$p ~=~\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}~=~m \dot{q},$$
  while $$P ~=~\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{Q}}~=~\frac{m}{\lambda^2}\dot{Q},$$
  so that $$P~=~\lambda^{-1} p.$$

See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/176555/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/134419/2451) related Phys.SE posts.

Answer (score 1):

If $\dot{Q}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial q}\dot{q}$ then $\dot{q}=\frac{\partial q}{\partial Q}\dot{Q}$ and by entering this in your formula you get the correct result.

Comment: What do you mean? Entering this into which formula?

Comment: In the $p=m\dot{q}$, then you will get the transform $p\rightarrow P$.

Comment: You started from the assumption $P=m\dot{Q}$, which is as @Qmechanic noted not necessarily true.