# If $(q,p)$ to $(Q,P)$ is a canonical transformation, then does this imply $(Q,P)$ to $(q,p)$ is also?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, poisson-brackets

If $(q,p)$ to $(Q,P)$ is a [canonical transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation), then does this imply $(Q,P)$ to $(q,p)$ is also, assuming Hamilton's equations hold for the coordinates $(q,p)$?

This seems like it should be true from the derivation for a canonical transformation using Poisson brackets, but I was wondering if anyone knew any better (or had some specific counter examples).

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): Note that there exist various definitions of a [canonical transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation) (CT) in the literature, cf. e.g. [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105613/2451) Phys.SE post and links therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A canonical transformation leaves the symplectic form on the cotangent bundle invariant. Hence its determinant is 1 globally, which means that your coordinate transformation can be inverted everywhere. The inverse transformation then preserves the symplectic form too, hence is a canonical transformation.