# Showing time-dependent transformations are canonical

Tags: classical-mechanics, time, hamiltonian-formalism, coordinate-systems, phase-space

In Goldstein's mechanics book he defines a canonical transformation as a transformation from $q, p$ to $Q, P$ with 
$$
Q = Q(q,p,t)  \tag{9.4a}
$$ and 
$$
P = P(q,p,t) \tag{9.4b}
$$ 
such that if $H$ is the Hamiltonian then there exists a $K$ and $F$ such that
$$ 
p_i \dot{q}_i - H = P_i \dot{Q}_i - K+  \frac{dF}{dt} \tag{9.11}.
$$ 
Later he shows that a time dependent canonical transformation satisfies the symplectic condition. He starts with a transformation of the form
$$
\boldsymbol{\zeta} = \boldsymbol{\zeta}(\boldsymbol{\eta}, t)\tag{9.59}$$ 
which is assumed to be canonical. Then there are two statements. The first is that the transformation $$\boldsymbol{\eta} \to \boldsymbol{\zeta}(t_0)\tag{9.60b}$$ is ''obviously'' canonical. The second is that the transformation $$\boldsymbol{\zeta}(t_0) \to \boldsymbol{\zeta}(t)\tag{9.60c}$$ is also canonical.

Now although these statements are intuitive, they do not seem obvious to me. With the first statement, it appears you must construct and $K$ and $F$ for the transformation to $\boldsymbol{\zeta}(
t_0)$ assuming these exist for the general time-dependent transformation. Would someone be able to help with my difficulties?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105613/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/197496/2451