# Do canonical transformations form a group?

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, group-theory

In a course on classical mechanics, we barely touched upon [canonical transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation) via generating functions. Just like Lorentz transformations form a group, I want to know if canonical transformations comply with a group structure. But what should be the group operation? In other words, is there a notion of "product" under which it is closed and associative?

1. **Existence of identity element:** Identity transformation is canonical because the coordinates are mapped to themselves.
2. **Existence of inverse:** Inverse of a canonical transformation is canonical since the Poisson brackets are invariant.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are, confusingly, different definitions of what exactly a "canonical transformation" is. See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/105670/50583) by Qmechanic for an extended discussion and more useful links. The definition of a transformation in terms of canonical coordinates $q,p$ (a fixed "Darboux chart") does not suffice to talk about these transformations in full generality since the phase space of a generic system is not guaranteed to be covered by a single such chart.

If we either take the viewpoint that a canonical transformation is a [symplectomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectomorphism) or an infinitesimal symplectomorphism as in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/197538/50583) by Qmechanic, then the group operation is simply "composition" - carry out the two transformations in succession. Symplectomorphisms are a group under composition: Diffeomorphisms are a group under composition and it's easy to show that the condition for being a symplectomorphism is also fulfilled for the composition of two symplectomorphisms.

Comment: +1. When will the group be abelian? Could you please tell me a resource to look more on this?

Comment: @expikx It is never Abelian (possible proof: The [real symplectic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_group) is always a subgroup and it is never Abelian). I'm not really sure what you're looking for in a reference, but one standard reference for symplectic geometry in classical mechanics would be Abraham's and Marsden's *Foundations of Mechanics*.