# Equivalence of symplectic condition and canonical transformation

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

In Goldstein's "Classical Mechanics", at page 384 it is claimed that given a point-transformation of phase space $$\underline{\zeta} = \underline{\zeta}(\underline{\eta}, t),\tag{9.59}$$ where $\underline{\eta}$ is a vector of canonical variables, then a necessary and sufficient condition for it to be canonical is the symplectic condition
$$MJM^T = J\tag{9.55}$$
where $M$ is the Jacobian of the transformation (i.e. the Jacobian of $\underline{\zeta}(\underline{\eta}, t)$ restricted to the derivatives with respect to $\underline{\eta}$) and $J$ is the skew-symmetric matrix of the form:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & I_l \\ 
-I_l & 0 
\end{bmatrix}\tag{8.38a}
$$

where $l$ denotes the number of degrees of freedom of the system.

Now, Goldstein first proves that this is true for restricted (i.e. time-independent) transformations, then he tries to do the same with a generic transformation but he just proves the symplectic condition to be a necessary condition and he does so by making use of infinitesimal canonical transformations. I have some problems with the latter derivation, especially when, at page 386, Goldstein claims that the transformation $\underline{\zeta}(t_0) \to \underline{\zeta}(t)$ can be written as "the succession of I.C.T.'s in steps of $dt$"; I tried making this statement rigorous by integrating but I had no success so far.

Therefore, I would like to know if anyone knows how to make the "necessary condition" part rigorous and how to prove the "sufficient condition" part.

---

As always any comment or answer is much appreciated and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Answer (score 3):

1. The main point is that an infinitesimal canonical transformation (ICT) of type 2 is an infinitesimal symplectomorphism (IS); and conversely, an IS is *locally* an ICT of type 2, cf. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/197538/2451).
2. The above infinitesimal relationship can in principle be integrated to a relationship for finite transformations. Note that there may be *global* obstructions for a [symplectomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectomorphism) (S) to be a [canonical transformation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105613/2451)$^1$ (CT) with a generating function $F$. Goldstein apparently ignores this.

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics;* chapter 9.

--

$^1$ See eq. (9.11) for Goldstein's definition of a CT.