# Canonical Transformations and Poisson Brackets - Sufficient and Necessary Condition for Canonical Transformation

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

I am currently taking analytical mechanics,

My professor directed us in the lecture to Hand and Finch, problem 6.9, to prove ourselves (as he didn't have time) that the equation $$[Q,P]_{Q,P} = [Q(q,p),P(q,p)]_{q,p} = 1\tag{6.39}$$
is both necessary and sufficient condition for the transformation between $q, p$, and $Q, P$ to be canonical (the exact phrasing of the question appears in the attached picture below).

I'm having trouble figuring out where to begin with this proof. Could someone provide a proof?

Please keep in mind that we haven't covered symplectic notation in class, so explanations without this concept would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/736608/2451 and links therein.