# Why isn't it important, after which coordinates the Variation of the action integral is done?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, variational-principle, variational-calculus

I often read,that if the lagrangian  $L=p\dot{q}-H$ of a pair of coordinates in phase space $(q,p)$ and $P\dot{Q}- K $, for some new pair of coordinates $(Q,P)$ only differ by a total time derivative $dF/dt$, the Variation of the action functional doesn't differ too, which implies that the canonical equations for the new coordinates hold.

My question now is: if the action functional $S(q,p,t)=S'(Q,P,t) + c$
where  $c= \int (dF/dt )dt $ is the integrated total time derivative of $F$ (which disappears in the Variation); why then is the variation of both sides equal? I mean surely the Variation of the $(q,p)$ coordinates would be the same for both sides, but why should the Variation of the $(Q,P)$ coordinates on the right hand side be the same as the Variation of the $(q,p)$ coordinates on the left hand side?

Comment: Because the new variables $Z^J\equiv (Q^j,P_j)$ are a fixed function (say, $f$) of the old variables $z^I\equiv (q^i,p_i)$ and $t$ (and vice versa).

Comment: ok thank you for the answer! is it so, because that implies that  Q(q+ ɛu(t),p+ ɛv(t),t) = Q+ ɛx(t)  for some arbitrary  functions u,v  so that x(t)  is arbitrary too? So that with  q(t, ɛ)=q + ɛu(t) , p(t, ɛ) = p + ɛv(t)  :                                           (dS(Q(q(t, ɛ),p(t, ɛ),t),P(q(t, ɛ),p(t, ɛ),t),t)/dɛ) ist the same as : ( dS(Q(t, ɛ),P(t, ɛ),t)/d ɛ) for ɛ = 0 ?  (sorry for my ugly writing, Im truly new to this site and can't yet write with mathematica or so )

Comment: We are varying both $Z^J$ and $z^I$, but not independently: We are not varying their inter-relational function $f$.

Comment: ok I think Im overlooking something there. I don't really understand how you vary Z^J and z^I at the same time if they are dependent on each other (as you say with the  function f) ? Doesn't varying one implie how the other coordinates change?

Comment: oh ok I see, so if we have function S(Q,P,t) and Q,P are again in a fixed relation to  (q,p) (with f), this implies that varying Q,P is the same as varying q,p for S ?

Comment: Yes, up to temporal boundary terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to stress that the $2n$ new variables $Z^J\equiv (Q^j,P_j)$ and the $2n$ old variables $z^I\equiv (q^i,p_i)$ are not $4n$ but only $2n$ independent variables.

We assume that the new variables $Z^J$ are a function of the old variables $z^I$ and time $t$ (and vice versa), and that the Jacobian matrix $\partial Z^J / \partial z^I$ is invertible.

In particular an infinitesimal variation $\delta z$ of $z$ induces a corresponding infinitesimal variation $\delta Z$ of $Z$.

See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/228909/2451) related Phys.SE post.