# Poisson brackets' property as necessary and sufficient condition for transformation to be canonical?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, coordinate-systems, phase-space, poisson-brackets

I read (Landau, Lifshitz: Mechanics)
[image]
and then 
[image]

---

I want to know if conditions (45.10) are **sufficient** for transformation $p,q \to P,Q$ to be canonical (obviously, they are necessary).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Condition (45.10) essentially defines a [symplectomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectomorphism). Some authors define a canonical transformation (CT) as a symplectomorphism, but not Landau & Lifshitz (L&L). They instead define a CT as a transformation 
$$\tag{1} (q^i,p_i)~~\mapsto~~ \left(Q^i(q,p,t),P_i(q,p,t)\right)$$
[together with choices of a Hamiltonian $H(q,p,t)$ and a Kamiltonian $K(Q,P,t)$; and where $t$ is the time parameter] that satisfies
$$ \tag{2} (p_i\mathrm{d}q^i-H\mathrm{d}t)
-(P_i\mathrm{d}Q^i -K\mathrm{d}t)
~=~\mathrm{d}F$$
for some generating function $F$, see the text between eqs. (45.5-6).

Since a symplectomorhism (45.10) states nothing about $H$ and $K$, the condition (45.10) is *not* sufficient to be a CT according to L&L.

Various definitions of CT and their interrelations are discussed in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105613/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: As far as I know the two conditions are (locally) equivalent if L-L's condition is stated more precisely by adding some quantifiers. "For every $H$ there are $K$ and  $F$ such that (2) holds."

Comment: @Valter Moretti: Agree.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, What does it mean that two conditions are equivalent locally?

Comment: The word _locally_ means in this context _in a sufficiently small open neighborhood._