# Canonical transformation of spacetime or under field theory formalism

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, poisson-brackets, adm-formalism

Is there a standard way to define [Canonical Transformations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/105613/which-transformations-are-canonical) in the case of field theory or spacetime?

I saw that under [ADM formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM_formalism) it is possible to define a [generating function](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Arnowitt-Deser-Misner_formalism#The_parameter_formalism):
$$
G(t)= \sum_i p_i \delta q_i - H\delta t
$$

But it's not clear what is the meaning of this generating function and why the transformations raise from it are canonical.

What's the definition of [the scholarpedia article](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Arnowitt-Deser-Misner_formalism#The_parameter_formalism) of the Poisson brackets $[A,B]$, how do they incorporate the time dimension into it?

Comment: Francis Tong "A Hamiltonian Formulation of General Relativity" (2006) http://www.math.toronto.edu/mccann/assignments/426/Tong.pdf