# Phase space volume doesn't change under canonical transform

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, coordinate-systems, phase-space, volume, poisson-brackets

I have given a set of generalized coordinates $(q_1,..q_n,p_1,..p_n)$. Suppose I had a canonical transform $(q_i,p_i)\rightarrow (Q_i,P_i).$ I am trying to show that the phase space volume element remains constant after the transform. I'm trying to understand the proof given in https://courses.smp.uq.edu.au/MATH4104/m4104sec3.pdf (Property 2)

I don't understand how $AJ_nA^T=\begin{bmatrix}
    \{Q_i,Q_j\}       & \{Q_i,P_j\} \\
    \{P_i,Q_j\}       & \{P_i,P_j\}   \\
\end{bmatrix}.$

For example for the first block matrix/first quadrant $(1\leq i,j\leq n)$ I get $$(AJ_nA^T)_{ij}=\left(-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial p_k}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial Q_j}{\partial q_k}\right)+\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial q_k}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial Q_j}{\partial p_k}\right)=
$$
$$
=\{Q_i,Q_j\}+x.
$$
$x$ only has terms $\partial Q_j/\partial p_i$ and  $\partial Q_j/\partial q_i$ where $i\neq j$.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/405244/2451

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by blocks:

$
   A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \partial _{q}Q & \partial _{p}Q \\
   \partial _{q}P & \partial _{p}P \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$,
$   A^{t}=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   (\partial _{q}Q)^{t} & (\partial _{p}Q)^{t} \\
   (\partial _{q}P)^{t} & (\partial _{p}P)^{t} \\
  \end{array} } \right]$
and therefore $JA^{t}=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   (\partial _{p}Q)^{t} & (\partial _{p}P)^{t} \\
   -(\partial _{q}Q)^{t} & -(\partial _{q}P)^{t} \\
  \end{array} } \right]$.

Now for example $(AJA^{t})_{11}=\partial _{q}Q(\partial _{p}Q)^{t}-\partial _{p}Q(\partial _{q}Q)^{t}$.

Remeber this is an equation on matrices. 
Write the matrices explicitly, for example $(\partial _{q}Q)_{ij}=\frac {\partial Q_{i}}  {\partial q_{j}} $,$(\partial _{p}Q)^{t}_{ij}=\frac {\partial Q_{j}}  {\partial q_{i}}$, and put them into the equation above, perform the matrix multiplication and get the Poisson brackets.