# Generating function for canonical transformation

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

Short version:

I've been reading through some notes on integrable systems/Hamiltonian dynamics, and am stuck on a problem: Show that the coordinate transformation derived via the generating function method gives you a canonical transformation.

Long version:

> A coordinate change $(\vec{q},\vec{p})\to (\vec{Q},\vec{P})$ is called canonical if it leaves Hamilton's equations invariant, i.e. the equations in the original coordinates
>   $$\dot{\vec{q}}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial\vec{p}},\quad \dot{\vec{p}}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial\vec{q}}$$
>   are equivalent to
>   $$\dot{\vec{Q}}=\frac{\partial\tilde{H}}{\partial\vec{P}}, \quad \dot{\vec{P}}=-\frac{\partial\tilde{H}}{\partial\vec{Q}}$$
>   where $\tilde{H}(\vec{Q},\vec{P})=H(\vec{q},\vec{p})$.

The generating function method:

> Suppose we have a function $S:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\to\mathbb{R}.$ Write its arguments $S(\vec{q},\vec{P})$. Now set
>   $$\vec{p}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial \vec{q}}, \quad \vec{Q}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial \vec{P}}.$$
>   The first equation lets us to solve for $\vec{P}$ in terms of $\vec{q},\vec{p}$. The second equation lets us solve for $\vec{Q}$ in terms of $\vec{q},\vec{P}$, and hence in terms of $\vec{q},\vec{p}$. The new coordinates $\vec{Q}$, $\vec{P}$ we find this way will give a canonical transformation. Checking this is just a careful application of the chain rule.

My Problem:

So I decided to try and work out this 'careful application of the chain rule', i.e. prove that the transformation obtained via this generating function method is canonical. I have been unable to do so, and help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

****my progress****

e.g. try to prove $\dot{\vec{P}}=-\frac{\partial\tilde{H}}{\partial\vec{Q}}$.
Thinking of $H$ as $H(\vec{q}(\vec{Q},\vec{P}),\vec{p}(\vec{Q},\vec{P}))$, and using the chain rule,
$$\frac{\partial\tilde{H}}{\partial Q_i}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial q_j}\frac{\partial q_j}{\partial Q_i}+\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_j}\frac{\partial p_j}{\partial Q_i}=-\dot{p}_j\frac{\partial q_j}{\partial Q_i}+\dot{q}_j\frac{\partial p_j}{\partial Q_i}$$
using the original Hamilton equations.

Meanwhile, 
$$-\dot{P}_i=-\frac{\partial P_i}{\partial q_j}\dot{q}_j-\frac{\partial P_i}{\partial p_j}\dot{p}_j,$$
so it will suffice to show 
$$\frac{\partial P_i}{\partial p_j}=\frac{\partial q_j}{\partial Q_i},\quad
\frac{\partial P_i}{\partial q_j}=-\frac{\partial p_j}{\partial Q_i}.$$
I've been able to show 
$$\frac{\partial p_j}{\partial P_i}=\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial q_j}$$
using chain rule and symmetry of partial derivatives. This then gives us the first desired equality, by inverting the Jacobian matrix:
$$\left[\frac{\partial p_j}{\partial P_i}\right]^{-1}
=\left[\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial q_j}\right]^{-1} \implies 
\left[\frac{\partial P_i}{\partial p_j}\right]
=\left[\frac{\partial q_j}{\partial Q_i}\right]$$

However, I'm not sure how to show
$$\frac{\partial P_i}{\partial q_j}=-\frac{\partial p_j}{\partial Q_i}.$$

Answer (score 2):

1. Recall that a coordinate transformation 
   $$(q^i,p_i)~~\mapsto~~ \left(Q^i(q,p,t),P_i(q,p,t)\right)\tag{1}$$
   with generating function $F$ is of the form$^1$
   $$\lambda\underbrace{(\sum_{i=1}^np_i\mathrm{d}q^i-H\mathrm{d}t)}_{~=:~\mathbb{L}_H}
   ~=~\underbrace{(\sum_{i=1}^nP_i\mathrm{d}Q^i -K\mathrm{d}t)}_{~=:~\mathbb{L}_K}
   ~+~\mathrm{d}F,\tag{2}$$
   where $\lambda\neq 0$ is a non-zero constant.
2. Since the 2 Lagrangian 1-forms $\mathbb{L}_H$ and $\mathbb{L}_K$ are the same off-shell up to a total derivative and an over-all multiplicative constant $\lambda$, they yield the same [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation), which clearly are Hamilton's equations in both cases. Hence the coordinate transformation (2) leaves Hamilton's equations form-invariant.
3. Eqs. (2) represent a notion of a [canonical transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation) (CT), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105613/2451) Phys.SE post.

--

$^1$ OP's generator $F=S(q,P,t)-\sum_{i=1}^nP_iQ^i$ is of [type 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Type_2_generating_function) and in OP's case $\lambda=1$.

Answer (score 0):

What you have found is basically another way to describe canonical transformations. Let's start by calculating
$$\dot{Q}_i = \frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial q_j} \dot{q}_j + \frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial p_j} \dot{p_j} = \frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial q_j} \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_j} - \frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial p_j} \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_j}.$$
This has to be equal to 
$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial P_i} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial q_j} \frac{\partial q_j}{\partial P_i} + \frac{\partial H}{\partial P_j}\frac{\partial p_j}{\partial P_i}.$$
Comparing these two equations yields 
$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_j} \left( \frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial q_j} - \frac{\partial p_j}{\partial P_i}\right) = \frac{\partial H}{\partial q_j}\left(\frac{\partial q_j}{\partial P_i} + \frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial p_j}\right).$$
Since neither $\partial H / \partial p_j$ nor $\partial H / \partial q_j$ are identical 0, the expressions in the brackets need to equal 0. In your case, you will have to show that the generating function $S$ yields a transformation that abides these equations (a similar argument for $\dot{P}_i$ yields the identiy in your question).

From a more theoretical point of few, a transformation is canonical if the poisson brackets are preserved:
$$\{Q_i, Q_j\} = 0, \qquad \{P_i, P_j\} = 0, \qquad \{Q_i, P_j\} = \delta_{ij}.$$
And from a even more abstract point of few, someone might show that a transformation is canonical by checking if it preserves the symplectic structure of Hamilton's equations. If $J$ is the Jacobian matrix and $E$ the $2n\times 2n$ matrix
$$ E = \begin{pmatrix}
0 &\delta_{ij}   \\
-\delta{ij} & 0 
\end{pmatrix} $$
then the symplectic structure is preserved iff
$J E J^\top = E$. Incidentally, $J$ is called symplectic in that case.

A canonical transformation induced by the generating function $S$ has to satisfy all three conditions, but since they are equivalent, you just need to check that one of them is true.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. When you say "In your case, you will have to show that the generating function $S$ yields a transformation that abides these equations" - this is precisely the bit I am stuck on! More specifically, how do I show the second bracket is equal to zero: $$\frac{\partial q_j}{\partial P_i}+\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial p_j}=0?$$

Comment: Just plug in the generating function with $Q_i = \frac{\partial S}{\partial P_j}$. Differentiate this expression with respect to $p_j$, which should yield $0$, since $S$ does not depend on $p_j$.

Comment: Not sure I agree with that. Strictly speaking if you were to differentiate a function with arguments $(\vec{q}, \vec{P})$ with respect to $p_j$ you would have to re express $\vec{P}$ as $\vec{P}(\vec{q},\vec{p})$. Your derivative then would then involve the chain rule and be nonzero
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial p_j}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial P_k}\frac{\partial P_k}{\partial p_j}.$$
Partial derivatives refer to a derivative w.r.t. a certain slot of the function's arguments.

Comment: I agree with you, my argument is regarding the derivative is not right. But i've been thinking of exploiting the symmetry of partial derivatives, i.e $$\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}\frac{\partial}{\partial P_k}S = \frac{\partial}{\partial P_k}\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}S$$. What do you think?

Comment: Hey, I found the 'official solution' after some browsing online. It's here if you're interested: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/acla2/IS_handout1.pdf. 
It turns out our approach might not have been the right one. Rather, you're meant to use the fact that a transformation
$$x\to y(x)$$
is canonical iff the Jacobian matrix $Dy$ is symplectic
$$Dy J (Dy)^T=J$$

Comment: Quite helpful and delightful