# One parameter-groups and coordinate transformations in phase-space

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, lie-algebra, phase-space

I have given a function

$$G=p_1q_1 - p_2q_2$$

on a 4-dimensional phase-space. This function $G$ commutes with the Hamiltonian

$$H= \frac{p_1p_2}{m} + m\omega^2q_1q_2.$$

It generates a flow

$$(\vec{q},\vec{p}) \rightarrow (\vec{Q}(\vec{q},\vec{p},\alpha), \vec{P}(\vec{q},\vec{p},\alpha)) $$

defined by

$$\frac{dQ_i}{d\alpha} = \frac{\partial G}{\partial P_i}; \quad \vec{Q}(\vec{q},\vec{p},0) = \vec{q}$$

$$\frac{dP_i}{d\alpha} = -\frac{\partial G}{\partial Q_i}; \quad \vec{P}(\vec{q},\vec{p},0) = \vec{p}.$$

The calculation is no problem, but I do not understand its background. How does $G$ generate the transformation and why is it first defined in old coordinates $\vec{q}, \vec{p}$ but then used with the new ones $\vec{Q}, \vec{P}$? What is the connection to (Lie-) group theory? And can the transformation be understood in terms of vector fields on a manifold?

Since the whole concept is not really clear to me I would be very grateful for a comprehensive explanation. Book-suggestion are also highly welcome.

Comment: Is this from a reference? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic this is a task form a beginner's course in theoretical physics, in which i am a tutor. Unfortunately I don't know where it is from.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of standard differential geometry, the phase space of physics is a [symplectic manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold) with symplectic structure $\omega = \mathrm{d}q^i \wedge \mathrm{d}p_i$ (with summation over repeated indices).

For any observable $f(q,p)$, the associated [Hamiltonian vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_vector_field) $X_f$ is defined abstractly by $\omega(X_f,V) = \mathrm{d}f(V)$ and in local coordinates this is the vector field $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_i}, -\frac{\partial f}{\partial q^i}\right)$. The [flows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field#Flow_curves) of Hamiltonian vector fields are [symplectomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectomorphism) of the phase space manifold, or what physicists know as "canonical transformation" in some contexts (but not always, see [this answer by Qmechanic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/105670/50583)).

So the one-parameter family of symplectomorphisms $\phi_t : (q^i, p_i)\mapsto (Q^i(t),P_i(t))$ generated as the flow of the Hamiltonian vector field associated with your function $G$ is the solution of the differential equations
\begin{align} 
\partial_t Q^i & = \frac{\partial G}{\partial p_i} \\
\partial_t P_i & = -\frac{\partial G}{\partial q^i}
\end{align}
and the usage of the capital coordinates on the r.h.s. in your equations is extremely likely to be a typo. Note that this can also be written as $\partial_t \phi_t = \{\phi_t , G\}$, which is more directly how one might say that $G$ generates the transformation - the infinitesimal change under the transformation is given by the Poisson bracket with $G$.

The connection to Lie theory is that the map $f \mapsto X_f$ from phase space functions to vector fields is a Lie algebra homomorphism with the Poisson bracket and the standard Lie bracket of vector fields as the Lie brackets on the two sides, and the flow $\phi_t$ associated with $X_f$ is the one-parameter group of elements of the diffeomorphism Lie group generated by $X_f$ (the latter is difficult to make precise in full generality because the group of diffeomorphisms is not finite-dimensional, but you can always do it for finite-dimensional subgroups and subalgebras).