# The relationship between symplectomorphism, canonical transformations, and the symplectic group

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

This is a follow up to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/562884/64998).

In the answer by Qmechanic, they state that the symplectic group, $Sp(2n,\mathbb{R})$, is the group of *linear, time-independent* canonical transformations.

If we consider a canonical transformation as a symplectomorphism on phase space (as per V. I. Arnold [here](https://www.google.com.au/books/edition/Mathematical_Methods_of_Classical_Mechan/5OQlBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover)), how can we restrict this to *linear* transformations? Since linearity is only defined if the phase space has a vector space structure, which in general it doesn't. More generally, how can we arrive at the symplectic group, from the symplectomorphisms on phase space?

Comment: Well, it's the Jacobian which satisfies the condition to be a symplectic group transformation, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let there be given a $2n$-dimensional [symplectic manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold) $(M,\omega)$.

1. OP is right that geometrically speaking the [symplectic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_group) $Sp(2n,\mathbb{R})$ is only guaranteed to be canonically/manifestly imbedded into the groupoid of [symplectomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectomorphism) if the manifold $M$ is a vector space.
2. Given a preferred/distinguished/fixed/fiducial [Darboux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem)/[canonical coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_coordinates) system $(q^1,\ldots,q^n,p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ with an origin, one can use it to define a linear structure in a neighborhood $U\subseteq M$, and in this way locally define a notion of linear transformations. (This is the pragmatic attitude of [my linked Phys.SE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/562889/2451).)