# Are all time-independent Hamiltonian systems related locally via time-independent canonical transformation?

Tags: coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

So recently I've been doing some self-study on canonical transformations and relating together different Hamiltonian systems.
I've found [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.4236/wjm.2012.25030) ([PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1012.2308&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) with a remarkable result showing that any two Hamiltonian systems $H(q,p)$ and $K(Q,P)$ with the same degrees freedom, are locally equivalent and connected via specific canonical transformation derived from the solution to the Hamiltonian-Jacobi equations.
The construction essentially shows (to my understanding) that the action functional can be looked at as a generating function mapping, which transforms the Hamiltonian to systems where nothing changes.
Applying this to both systems $H$ and $K$ and requiring that the constants match links the two systems.
However, this construction goes through the HJ canonical transformation, which is time-dependent as it essentially contains information on the dynamics of the original system.
Nevertheless, the canonical transformations that connect both systems together in their examples always end up being time-independent.

So my question is for something I did not currently see a clear idea how to prove or disprove - given two Hamiltonian systems $H(q,p)$ and $K(Q,P)$ with the same degrees of freedom is it true that there always exists a time-independent canonical transformation $f: (q,p) \to (Q,P)$ such that the dynamics of $K(f(q,p))$ in terms of $(q,p)$ are the same as the dynamics of $H(q,p)$ (at least locally since the transformation might not be one-to-one)?

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: The answer is *No,* since a time-independent [canonical transformation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105613/2451) (CT) cannot turn a non-zero Hamiltonian into a vanishing Hamiltonian. However OP's conjecture is true for 2 non-zero sufficiently well-behaved Hamiltonians.

More details:

1. In the same way as time-dependent [Hamilton-Jacobi (HJ) theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation), is governed by [Hamilton's principal function](https://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/HamiltonsPrincipalFunction.html) $S(q,P,t)$, the corresponding time-independent problem is governed by Hamilton's characteristic function $W(q,P)$, cf. e.g. Ref. 1.
2. The underlying mathematical problem comes down to guaranteeing the local existence of a solution to the time-independent HJ equation, which is a first-order non-linear PDE. To ensure this, OP's 2 Hamiltonians $H$ & $\widetilde{H}$ would have to be sufficiently well-behaved.
3. One new feature (in the time-independent case) is that the 2 Kamiltonians $K$ & $\widetilde{K}$ (produced by time-independent HJ theory) are not necessarily zero (as in the time-dependent case), so as an extra step one should make CTs to ensure that $K=P_1$ and $\widetilde{K}=\widetilde{P}_1$. (This last step could fail if precisely one of the Kamiltonians vanishes.) $\Box$

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics;*  Section 10.3.

Comment: can you expand a bit on the following obvious example: turn (or at least relate by CT) $H=p^2/2+ x^2/2$ to $\tilde H=p^2/2-x^2/2$?