# Noetherian versus Hamiltonian symmetries

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, noethers-theorem, phase-space

There are 2 ideas of symmetry I have seen in Classical Mechanics:

1. Noetherian symmetry: Here they discuss infinitesimal point transformations where only position coordinates (and their derivatives ) get perturbed. They define symmetry to be those infinitesimal transformations where Lagrangian is not changed. Noether's theorem then relates these symmetric transformations to a conserved quantity $Q = \sum_i p_i f_i(q)$
2. Hamiltonian symmetry: Here they discuss the idea infinitesimal canonical transformations (ICT), which are actually in (q,p) phase space. It is then shown that the ICT generated by $G$ is a symmetry of Hamiltonian iff $G$ is conserved in time as system evolves by $H$.

I wanted to know if these 2 are equivalent in some sense or not. There are some obvious differences such as the first one is in $q$ space and second in $(q,p)$ space and ICT will allow $G$ (and consequently the transformations) to be dependent on time. But we see that in both cases a translation symmetry leads to a conserved linear momentum and a rotational symmetry leads to a conserved angular momentum.

My query is that is there any formal result which combines the 2 ideas of symmetry?

Specifically is one of these symmetries a subset of the other?

Comment: I'm pretty sure both phenomena are considered cases of Noether's theorem.  You might enjoy [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.14741)

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to consider the Hamiltonian version of Noether theorem, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69271/2451) Phys.SE. Then the Noether symmetries correspond to [Hamiltonian vector fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_vector_field) (HVF), or infinitesimal [symplectomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectomorphism), which in turn correspond to infinitesimal [canonical transformations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105613/2451) (ICT).