# Condition for a time-dependent transformation to be a canonical transformation

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, time, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

I'm looking for a sufficient condition to determine if a given transformation is a [canonical transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation). I have found two conditions, but they are only valid for the case that the transformation is is time-independent (*i.e.*, a restricted canonical transformation); if $F$ is the generating function,

$$pdq-PdQ=dF \tag{1}$$

$$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial q} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial p} \quad;\quad \frac{\partial Q}{\partial p} = -\frac{\partial P}{\partial q} \tag{2}$$

Is there a general condition for determining if an arbitrary transformation is canonical? For example, how would we deterimine if the following transformation is canonical?

$$Q=q$$
$$P=p+\frac{\partial \Phi(q,t)}{\partial q}$$

With $\Phi(q,t)$ an arbitrary funcion of the generalized coordinate $q$ and the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Which transformations are canonical?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105613/2451)

Comment: Your example preserves PBs.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos This example is indeed supposed to be a canonical transformation, but, in $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial q} \frac{\partial P}{\partial p}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial p} \frac{\partial P}{\partial q}=1-\frac{\partial^2 \Phi(q,t)}{\partial q^2}$, wouldn't $\frac{\partial^2 \Phi(q,t)}{\partial q^2}$ need to be zero? (Thanks for the PB trick)

Comment: No. Your second term vanishes by dint of dQ/dp=0.