# Generating Functions for Extended Canonical Transformations

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

From Goldstein we have that, for non-extended ($\lambda =1 $), the [generating function of third type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Type_3_generating_function) is $$F = F_3(p,Q,t) + q_ip_i.\tag{1}$$
Although I found it hard to see if that would hold true also for extended canonical transformations ($\lambda \neq 1$). 
The only reference I found claims that in these cases
$$F = F_3(p,Q,t) + \lambda q_ip_i\tag{2}$$
although they provide no proof nor explanation, and I have been having hard times convincing myself of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's eq. (2) is correct. Using the definition of an extended [CT](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105613/2451):
$$ \lambda(\sum_{i=1}^np_i\mathrm{d}q^i-H\mathrm{d}t)
-(\sum_{i=1}^nP_i\mathrm{d}Q^i -K\mathrm{d}t)
~=~\mathrm{d}F,\tag{9.8}$$
we derive the extended [type 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Type_3_generating_function) conditions:
$$ \begin{align}
\lambda q^i~=~&- \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial p_i}, \cr
P_i~=~&- \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial Q^i}, \cr
K~=~&\lambda H+ \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial t}
.\end{align} \tag{9.20'}$$