# Proof that canonical transformations implies symplectic condition

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

Goldstein's Classical Mechanics makes the claim (pages 382 to 383) that given coordinates $q,p$, Hamiltonian $H$, and new coordinates $Q(q,p),P(q,p)$, there exists a transformed Hamiltonian $K$ such that $\dot Q_i = \frac{\partial K}{ \partial P_i}$ and $\dot P_i = -\frac{\partial K}{Q_i}$ *if and only if* $MJM^T= J$ where $M$ is the Jacobian of $Q,P$ with respect to $q,p$ and $J = \begin{bmatrix}
O&I\\\\
-I&O
\end{bmatrix}$. I understood the book's proof that $MJM^T= J$ implies the existence of such $K$. However, the proof of the converse was not given and I do not know how to derive it myself despite the book saying (page 383)

> That Eq. (9.55) is also a necessary condition for a restricted canonical transformation is easily shown directly by reversing the order of the steps of the proof

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105613/2451