# Can all canonical transformation be obtained through generation function approaches?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

The question can be formulated as following:

Suppose 
$$\delta \int_{t_1}^{t_2}{[p\cdot \dot{q} - H(p,q,t) ]dt} = 0$$
$$\delta \int_{t_1}^{t_2}{[P\cdot \dot{Q} - K(P,Q,t) ]dt} = 0$$

in which $$P = P(p,q,t), Q = Q(p,q,t)$$ is an invertible transformation.

Can we prove that there must exist a $\lambda$ and function $G(p,q,t)$ (or $G(p,Q,t)$, $G(P,Q,t)$, $G(P,q,t)$), such that 
$$\lambda[p\cdot \dot{q} - H(p,q,t) ] = [P\cdot \dot{Q} - K(P,Q,t) ] + \frac{dG}{dt}~?$$

Answer (score 4):

Before we begin, note first of all, that there exist various definitions of a [canonical transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation) (CT) in the literature, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105613/2451) Phys.SE post. For instance, OP's last equation (v1) is called an *extended canonical transformation* (ECT) in Ref. 1.

OP is essentially asking (v1):

> *If we have a transformation
>   $$\tag{A} (q,p)~\longrightarrow~ (Q,P)$$
>   (with possible explicit time dependence) that transforms the Hamilton's eqs. into Kamilton's eqs., will it be an ECT, at least locally?*

The answer is: *No, not necessarily.* For instance, the example in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89025/2451) Phys.SE post is a counterexample. This can be shown by a slight modification of the proof in eqs. (4)-(7) of [my answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/89298/2451) in order to allow an arbitrary scale factor $\lambda$.

For completeness, let us mention that the opposite of (A) is true: An ECT transforms the Hamilton's eqs. into Kamilton's eqs. This follows because their two action functionals $S_K=\lambda S_H$ are proportional to each other (up to boundary terms). Therefore the [EL eqs.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) (=Hamilton's eqs.) for $S_H$ corresponds to the EL eqs. (=Kamilton's eqs.) for $S_K$.

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics,* Chapter 9. See text under eq. (9.11).