# Can all the systems have a Hamiltonian description?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism

I have heard of mechanical systems that might not have a Hamiltonian dynamics, but I cannot figure out an example that supports it.

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34834/2451 Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51510/2451

Comment: Oh you are right, should I delete the post?
Thank you!