# How do non-conservative forces affect Lagrange equations?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, dissipation, conservative-field

If we have a system and we know all the degrees of freedom, we can find the Lagrangian of the dynamical system. What happens if we apply some non-conservative forces in the system? I mean how to deal with the Lagrangian, if we get any external non-conservative forces perturbs the system?

Example:

We have a mass $m$ that is attached with a massless spring.

We could write the Lagrangian  as $L= \frac{1}{2} m \dot x ^2 + mgx - \frac{1}{2} k x^2$.

What happens to this equation if we consider any non-conservative forces?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

More generally, [Lagrange equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics)$^1$ read

$$\begin{align} \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial (T-U)}{\partial \dot{q}^j}-\frac{\partial (T-U)}{\partial q^j}~=~&Q_j-\frac{\partial{\cal F}}{\partial\dot{q}^j}+\sum_{\ell=1}^m\lambda^{\ell} a_{\ell j}, \cr j~\in \{1,\ldots, n\},\end{align} \tag{L}$$

where

- $q^1,\ldots ,q^n,$ are $n$ [generalized position coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates);
- $T$ is the kinetic energy;
- $U$ is a generalized potential;
- ${\cal F}$ is the [Rayleigh dissipation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_dissipation_function) for friction forces;
- $Q_1,\ldots ,Q_n,$ are the remaining parts of the generalized forces, which are not described by the generalized potential $U$ or the Rayleigh dissipation function ${\cal F}$;
- $\lambda^1,\ldots ,\lambda^m$, are $m$ [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) for $m$ [semi-holonomic constraints](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/410110/2451)
  $$\begin{align}  \sum_{j=1}^n a_{\ell j}(q,t)\dot{q}^j+a_{\ell t}(q,t)~=~0,  \cr \ell~\in ~&\{1,\ldots, m\}. \end{align}\tag{SHC}$$
  One may think of the last term on the right-hand side of eq. (L) as the generalized constraint forces for the semi-holonomic constraints (SHC). All other constraints are assumed to be [holonomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints).

For a discussion of conservative & non-conservative forces, see also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31672/2451) Phys.SE post.

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics;* Chapter 1 & 2.

--

$^1$ We distinguish between Lagrange equations (L) and [Euler-Lagrange  equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)
$$\begin{align} \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^j}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial q^j}~=~&0, \cr j~\in~&\{1,\ldots, n\}.\end{align}\tag{EL} $$
In contrast to the Lagrange equations (L), the EL equations are by definition always assumed to be derived from a [stationary action principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary-action_principle).
We should stress that it is not possible to apply the stationary action principle to derive the Lagrange equations (L) unless all generalized forces have generalized potentials $U$. See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20298/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147341/2451) Phys.SE posts.

Comment: Good answer.  Also googling Lagrange multiplier should turn up related info.