# Exact differential equations and holonomic constraints

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, differential-equations, constrained-dynamics

I understand that if a constraint equation given on a differential form is exact, that means it is also holonomic since I can find a solution. But there are other types of differential equations, like separable and linear, such that I can find an equation in the form of a holonomic constraint. Why is it that being exact is a condition, rather than just having a solution of the type $f(x,y) = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

1. Here I would like to mention the notion of a [semi-holonomic constraint](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=semi+holonomic+constraint) 
   $$ \sum_{j=1}^n a_j(q,t)~ \mathrm{d}q^j + a_t(q,t)~\mathrm{d}t~=~0, \tag{1'}$$
   which puts an
   [inexact differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inexact_differential) equal to zero.
2. It is possible to incorporate semi-holonomic constraints into Lagrange equations, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/283289/2451).
3. Note that eq. (1') does *not* mean that we demand that the $n+1$ co-vector components 
   $$ a_t(q,t)~= a_1(q,t)~= \ldots ~=~a_n(q,t)~=~0 \qquad\qquad (\longleftarrow \text{Wrong!} )
   \tag{2'}$$
   of a co-vector (1') should be zero. Perhaps this potential misunderstanding (2') is secretly the core of OP's question?
4. Rather eq. (1') means that
   $$ \sum_{j=1}^n a_j(q,t)~ \dot{q}^j + a_t(q,t)~=~0. \tag{3'}$$
5. In particular, a [holonomic constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints) 
   $$f(q,t)~=~0 \tag{0}$$ 
   can be put on the above semi-holonomic form 
   $$ \mathrm{d}f~=~\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial q^j}~ \mathrm{d}q^j +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}~\mathrm{d}t~=~0 .\tag{1}$$
   Explicitly, eq. (1) means that the total time derivative
   $$ \frac{df}{dt}~\equiv~ \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial q^j}~ \dot{q}^j +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}~=~0\tag{3}$$
   is zero.

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics,* Section 2.4.