# Holonomic and non-holonomic constraints

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, constrained-dynamics

1. Is it possible for a system to have [holonomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints) and non-holonomic constraints at the same time?
2. If so, in this scenario does it make sense to talk about a set of independent ['generalized coordinates'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. E.g. take your favorite $d$-dimensional non-holonomic system and pretend that it lives in $d+1$ dimensions by imposing a holonomic constraint that the extra dimension is a constant.
2. No, not in the conventional sense of the word [generalized coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates) $(q^1, \ldots, q^n)$. They are by definition constructed out of a larger set of coordinates [typically $({\bf r}_1, \ldots, {\bf r}_N)$] by imposing a set of [holonomic constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints) only. If we now impose further [e.g. non-holonomic$^\dagger$] constraints, the generalized coordinates  $(q^1, \ldots, q^n)$ wont be completely independent anymore.

--

$^\dagger$ Semiholonomic constraints can be implemented with the help of [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/283289/2451).

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

> A [holomonic constraint](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints) in classical mechanics are relations between the position variables (and possibly time)

And this means that a constraint can be written as

> $f(q_1,...,q_n,t) =0

Where of course the variables $q_1,...,q_n$ are the usual generalised position variables.

Thus a non-holonomic constraint is one that includes a dependence upon a generalised velocity.

Since we can have more than one constraint, it's obviously possible to have a holonomic and non-holonomic constraint.