# How can Lagrangian method work whenever the Lagrangian is not convex?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

Let $$L(x,\dot x)=\frac{1}{2}m\dot x^2-\frac{1}{2}k(x-x_0)^2-mgx$$ the Lagrangian of a system. Euler Lagrange theorem says that a necessary condition to be a minimizer is to satisfy Euler-Lagrange condition. It's sufficient if the Lagrangian is convex. The method of Euler-Lagrange consist in finding solution of $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x},$$
and after, we say that the solution will give the minimizer. But since the Lagrangian is not convex, how can this method work?

Answer (score 0):

1. The underlying variational principle for [EL equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) is a principle of [stationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point) action, despite that it is often referred to as a [principle of least/minimal action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action).
2. Also note that Lagrange equations may not have an action principle to begin with, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283238/2451) Phys.SE post.