# Why do we integrate over the Lagrangian to get action?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

As action is defined as

$$S = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}{\mathcal{L}(q,\dot{q},t)}dt $$

For any time interval $(t_1, t_2)$.

As $t_1$ and $t_2$ are arbitrary $t_2$ can be taken arbitrarily close to $t_1$ and we could drop the integral sign.

Why isn't that the case?

Comment: "as t_1 and t_2 are arbitrary t2 can be taken arbitrarily close to t1", you are descibing differentiation:d/dt

Comment: You can in special cases where the Lagrangian is constant over the time interval of interest.  For any time interval *of interest*.  An infinitely short time interval would often (usually) not be of interest.  There is usually a well-defined beginning and ending over which there are non-trivial dynamics (Lagrangian not constant).

Answer (score 2):

1. Well, it is possible to work directly with the Lagrangian in [Lagrange's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics), cf. e.g [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283238/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. However, if one wants to have a [variational principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_principle) that leads to [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation), it is necessary to introduce the [action functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics)#Action_(functional)) $S=\int_{t_i}^{t_f}\! dt~L$. This leads to the [principle of stationary action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action)/[Hamilton's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%27s_principle). Recall that if the Lagrangian $L$ depends on generalized velocities $\dot{q}^j$, it is necessary to integrate by parts to derive the EL equations. If one drops the time-integration in $S$, as OP suggests, this derivation becomes impossible.

Comment: But can't we derive the EL equations by considering the variation of action over an infinitesimal time interval $t_1$ to $t_1+\epsilon$ ? I think we would get the the incorrect equation, but why is that the case?

Comment: Note that the word _infinitesimal_ is often slippery.