# Is there alway exist a Lagrangian in the form of $L=T-C(\{q_i\},\{\dot q_i\},t)$, where $C$ contains no algebraical rewrite of $T$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

The Lagrangian equation is
$$\frac{d}{{dt}}\frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial {{\dot q}_j}}} - \frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial {q_j}}} = {Q_j}$$
Following D'Alembert's Principle
$$\left( {\frac{d}{{dt}}\frac{{\partial T}}{{\partial {{\dot q}_j}}} - \frac{{\partial T}}{{\partial {q_j}}}} \right) - {Q_j} = 0$$
When $Q_j$ fits one of the following two conditons the Lagrangian is in the form $L=T-U$, with $U$ being the potential
$$
{Q_j} = - \frac{{\partial U}}{{\partial {q_j}}}\\
\ \\
\text{or}\\
\ \\
{Q_j} = - \frac{{\partial U}}{{\partial {q_j}}} + \frac{d}{{dt}}\frac{{\partial U}}{{\partial {{\dot q}_j}}}
$$

---

Suppose now I manually define a scalar term $C(\{q_i\},\{\dot q_i\},t)$ such that

$$ {\frac{d}{{dt}}\frac{{\partial (T - C)}}{{\partial {{\dot q}_j}}} - \frac{{\partial (T - C)}}{{\partial {q_j}}}} = {Q_j} - \frac{d}{{dt}}\frac{{\partial C}}{{\partial {{\dot q}_j}}} + \frac{{\partial C}}{{\partial {q_j}}}$$

and rewrite the above equation into the following form:

$$ {\frac{d}{{dt}}\frac{{\partial (T - C)}}{{\partial {{\dot q}_j}}} - \frac{{\partial (T - C)}}{{\partial {q_j}}}} = Q_j'$$

I can again obtain an expression similar to the lagrangian equation

---

Now can I choose this $(T-C)$ term as my Lagrangian of the system and treat $Q_j'$ as some kind of friction?

Does this mean: there alway exists a Lagrangian in the form of $L=T-C(\{q_i\},\{\dot q_i\},t)$, where $C$ contains no algebraical rewrite of $T$?

(By not an algebraical rewrite I meant $C \ne aT^b+k$)

Comment: What are you asking? Your final paragraph seems to presuppose that you already have a lagrangian $L$ and a kinetic energy $T$, and we already know that $L=L(q,\dot q, t)$ in general. So are you just asking whether you can "always" write $C(q,\dot q, t) = T(\dot q) - L(q,\dot q, t)$? I don't see why you can't write that down...

Comment: I may be missing the point. The Lagrangian is a function $L(q_i, \dot{q}_i, t)$. If you know this function and you know $T$ then you can always define $C = T-L$ and you will have the Lagrangian in the form $L = T-C$ by construction.

Comment: @Gold, ah my bad... I think what I meant is: Is it true that the Lagrangian is generally in the form of $$L=T-C$$ with $T$ being the kinetic energy and $C$ being some scalar function (not necessarily the potential)

Comment: But you see, $T$ is known. In that case, whatever $L$ is if you *define* $C$ to be $C=T-L$ by construction the Lagrangian will have the form you ask for. An entirely different question is if you start to demand something of $C$. For example, if you demand $C$ to depend just on generalized coordinates, $C = C(q_i)$. Then that won't be true. But if you allow $C$ to be any function whatsover of $(q_i,\dot{q}_i,t)$ then what you ask is trivially true because, again, you can just define $C = T-L$.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/50075/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283238/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. But it doesn't matter if the RHS still has a $Q_j'$. You've just swapped your ignorance of $Q_j$ with your ignorance of $Q_j'$.

> When $Q_j$ fits one of the following two conditons the Lagrangian is in the form $L=T-U$
> $$
> {Q_j} = - \frac{{\partial U}}{{\partial {q_j}}}\\
> \ \\
> \text{or}\\
> \ \\
> {Q_j} = - \frac{{\partial U}}{{\partial {q_j}}} + \frac{d}{{dt}}\frac{{\partial U}}{{\partial {{\dot q}_j}}}
> $$

Writing $L=T-V$ isn't the point here. The point is : For the above two cases you mentioned, You can write $L=T-V$ satisfying:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}=0 \quad (\star)
\end{equation}

The $=0$ on the RHS is why these two cases are so special. In such cases, it's easier to obtain the equations of motion than if there were a $Q_j$ sitting on the RHS.

You can write $L=T-C$, as you did:

> Suppose now I manually define a scalar term $C(\{q_i\},\{\dot q_i\},t)$ such that
> $$ {\frac{d}{{dt}}\frac{{\partial (T - C)}}{{\partial {{\dot q}_j}}} - \frac{{\partial (T - C)}}{{\partial {q_j}}}} = {Q_j} - \frac{d}{{dt}}\frac{{\partial C}}{{\partial {{\dot q}_j}}} + \frac{{\partial C}}{{\partial {q_j}}}$$
> and rewrite the above equation into the following form:
> $$ {\frac{d}{{dt}}\frac{{\partial (T - C)}}{{\partial {{\dot q}_j}}} - \frac{{\partial (T - C)}}{{\partial {q_j}}}} = Q_j'$$

but there will still be a $Q_j'$ on the RHS. This $L$ *isn't even a Lagrangian* as it does not satisfy the Euler-Lagrange equation ($\star$). Funnily enough, it would've been simpler to not bother with $C$ at all, as $C$ is simply useless and only complicates the mathematics unless you manage to reduce the RHS to zero.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. But what if I choose to treat the $Q_j'$ as some kind of friction force in this case? Can I still call $L$ the Lagrangian with $Q_j'$ being the friction?

Comment: If you give me a Lagrangian, I should be able to plug it into EL equation ($\star$) and extract the equations of motion, no questions asked. If you give me some $L$ and also give me some equation(that isn't ($\star$) ) to plug it into, then that $L$ isn't a Lagrangian. Any Lagrangian should satisfy ($\star$)

Comment: what you can do perhaps is write a $L_c$ which is some conservative lagrangian for the system and push all the non-conservative behaviour to the RHS, which in some cases will turn out to be of some significance, like Rayleigh's dissipation function. Then again, it's just a matter of convention and what you truly call a Lagrangian is something that satisfies ($\star$).