# Hamiltonian from a Lagrangian with constraints?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

Let's say I have the Lagrangian:
$$L=T-V.$$
Along with the constraint that $$f\equiv f(\vec q,t)=0.$$ We can then write:
$$L'=T-V+\lambda f. $$
What is my Hamiltonian now? Is it
$$H'=\dot q_i p_i -L'~?$$
Or something different? I have found at least one example where using the above formula gives a different answer then the Hamiltonian found by decreasing the degrees of freedom by one rather then using Lagrange multipliers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comments to the question (v2):

To go from the [Lagrangian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) to the [Hamiltonian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics) formalism, one should perform a (possible singular) [Legendre transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation). Traditionally this is done via the Dirac-Bergmann recipe/cookbook, see e.g. Refs. 1-2. Note in particular, that the constraint $f$ may generate a [secondary constraint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_constraint)

$$g ~:=~ \{f,H^{\prime}\}_{PB} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}~\approx~\frac{d f}{d t}~\approx~0.$$

[Here the $\approx$ symbol means equality modulo eqs. of motion or constraints.]

References:

1. P.A.M. Dirac, *Lectures on QM,* (1964).
2. M. Henneaux and C. Teitelboim, *Quantization of Gauge Systems,* 1994.

Comment: 3. P.A.M. Dirac, [Can. J. Math. 2 (1950) 129](http://dx.doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1950-012-1).

Answer (score 5):

The Hamiltonian is defined by
$$ H = \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q_i} \dot q_i \right) - L $$
So in your case: $ H' = H - \lambda f $