# Why is the Hamiltonian zero in relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, energy, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

I'm trying to understand something with the lagrangian and the hamiltonian formalisms in relativity theory, and why the following result cannot be the same in classical (non-relativistic) mechanics.  There's something missing or badly defined in my reasoning, and I don't see what yet.

Consider a system of "particles", of generalized coordinates $q^i(t)$ in some reference frame.  The *action* of the system is defined as the following integral :
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
S = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} L(q^i, \dot{q}^i) \, dt.
\end{equation}
The *hamiltonian* of the system is defined as this (summation is implied on the repeated indices) :
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
H = \dot{q}^i \, \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^i} - L.
\end{equation}
Now consider a change of parametrization in integral (1) ; $dt = \theta \, ds$, where $s$ is a new integration variable and $\theta(s)$ is an arbitrary function that could be considered as a new dynamical variable (there's something missing in my interpretation, and I need to find what is "wrong" here).  The action is now this (the prime is the derivative with respect to $s$.  Notice the change of limits, on this integral) :
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
S = \int_{s_1}^{s_2} L(q^i, \frac{q^{i \, \prime}}{\theta}) \; \theta \; ds.
\end{equation}
So the new lagrangian is
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
\tilde{L} = L(q^i, \frac{q^{i \, \prime}}{\theta}) \; \theta.
\end{equation}
Now, if $\theta$ is considered as a dynamical variable, we can apply the Euler-Lagrange to this new lagrangian:
\begin{equation}\tag{5}
\frac{d}{d s} \Big( \frac{\partial \tilde{L}}{\partial \, \theta^{\, \prime}} \Big) - \frac{\partial \tilde{L}}{\partial \, \theta} = 0.
\end{equation}
Since there is no $\theta^{\, \prime}$ in $\tilde{L}$, the first part is 0.  After some simple algebra, the second part implies that the hamiltonian (2) should be 0 !
\begin{equation}\tag{6}
H \equiv 0.
\end{equation}

So my questions are these:

> 1. Is there something wrong in the previous reasoning?  Or what ***implicit assumptions*** am I missing?  Where is relativity in this?
> 2. If the reasoning is valid, why can't we apply the result to any classical lagrangian, which would give non-sense?

Of course, I know that the hamiltonian of free relativistic particles isn't 0!  But I also know that $H = 0$ is a well known property of systems which have an action with *parametrization independence*.  I'm missing some parts related to this constraint and I don't see what yet.  I need help to disentangle this subject.

Answer (score 14):

1. The correct argument for how reparametrization invariance implies vanishing Hamiltonian is as follows: Given a generic Hamiltonian action
   $$ S = \int \left(\dot{q}^i p_i - u^\alpha \chi_\alpha - H\right)\mathrm{d}t,$$
   where $q,p$ are the canonical phase space variables, $\chi_\alpha$ are Hamiltonian constraints with Lagrange multipliers $u^\alpha$ and $H(q,p)$ is the actual Hamiltonian on non-extended phase space, the action being time-reparametrization invariant forces the Hamiltonian to be zero *only* if the $q,p$ transform as scalars under the time-reparametrization $t\mapsto \tau(t)$ (since then $\dot{q}^i p_i \mapsto \frac{\mathrm{d}\tau}{\mathrm{d}t} q'^i p_i$ (the prime $'$ denotes the derivative w.r.t. $\tau$)) and if the constraint terms $u^\alpha\chi_\alpha$ also transform as scalar densities $u^\alpha \chi_\alpha \mapsto \frac{\mathrm{d}\tau}{\mathrm{d}t} u^\alpha \chi_\alpha$. Under these assumptions, $H=0$ follows because if $q,p$ are scalars then so is $H(q,p)$, and $H(q,p)$ therefore cannot transform as a scalar density to preserve invariance of the action, and must be zero.

Note that the derivative in $\mathrm{d}t = \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\mathrm{d}\tau$ (which is called $\theta$ in the question) is *not a dynamical variable* from the viewpoint of the original system. Your Euler-Lagrange equation does not exist because it is not a function/coordinate on phase space.

Note also that, if $s_1 \neq t_1$ and $s_2\neq t_2$, the transformation $t\mapsto s$ you perform is not what is generally called a *time-reparametrization* in the context where we talk about reparametrization invariance and vanishing Hamiltonians. It is usually assumed that the start and end of the parameter stay fixed.

2. Your new system $\bar{L}$ is not equivalent to the original one: You can, however, define a new Lagrangian system $\bar L(q,q',\theta,{\theta}') := L(q,q'/\theta)\theta$, with an additional variable $\theta$, if you so desire. Let's examine that new system a bit:

   The equations of motion for $q$ are
   $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\left(\frac{\partial\bar{L}}{\partial q'}\right) - \frac{\partial\bar{L}}{\partial q} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\left(\frac{\partial(L\theta)}{\partial q'}\right) - \frac{\partial(L\theta)}{\partial q} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\left(\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial q'}\right)\theta + \frac{\partial L}{\partial q'}\theta' - \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial q}\theta = 0\tag{a}$$
   and the equation of motion for $\theta$ is
   $$ \frac{\partial \bar{L}}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} \theta + L = 0.\tag{b}$$
   Here, crucially, $L$ has to be read as the $L(q,q'/\theta)$ it appears as in the $\bar{L}$, so we have 
   $$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial q'} = \frac{1}{\theta} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\partial (q'/\theta)}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} = -\frac{q'}{\theta^2}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} \tag{c}$$
   in terms of the $\partial L /\partial \dot{q}$ that appears in the original E-L equations. Notably, eq. (b) indeed implies that $\dot{q}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} - L = 0$ **but only** under the assumption that $q'/\theta = \dot{q}$. However, the moment we promoted $\theta$ to a dynamical variable, we *lost that relation* - the object $\dot{q}$ does not exist in this new world anymore, the $\partial L/\partial \dot{q}$ is a function of $q,q'$ and $\theta$, not one of $q$ and $\dot{q}$. From the viewpoint fo the new system it should be read simply as $\frac{\partial L}{\partial(q'/\theta)}$.

   Let us now plug eq. (c) into eq. (a):
   $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\left(\frac{1}{\theta} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\right)\theta + \frac{1}{\theta} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\theta' - \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial q}\theta = -\frac{\theta'}{\theta}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} + \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\left(\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}\right) + \frac{\theta'}{\theta}\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}- \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial q}\theta = 0$$
   $$ \implies \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\left(\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}\right) - \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial q}\theta = \frac{1}{\theta}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\left(\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}\right) - \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial q} = 0\tag{d}$$
   If the two Lagrangian systems $L(q,\dot{q})$ and $\bar{L}(q,q',\theta,\theta')$ were equivalent, the equations of motion of $\bar{L}$ should reduce to the equations of motion of $L$ upon use of the equation of motion for $\theta$. But eq. (b) does not make that possible - inserting it into eq. (d) does not lend itself to simplications by which we would obtain the original equations of motion. The relation we *actually* need would be, once again, $q'/\theta = \dot{q}$.
3. Here is the Lagrangian argument for how reparametrization invariance implies vanishing Hamiltonian: If the original action was time-reparameterization invariant, we have that, under an infintesimal reparametrization $\delta t = \theta(t)$ with induced changes
   $$\delta q = \dot{q}\theta \quad \delta \dot{q} = \dot{\delta q} = \ddot{q}\theta + \dot{q}\dot{\theta} \quad \theta(t_1) = \theta(t_2) = 0 $$
   the change induced in the Lagrangian is zero, i.e.
   $$ \delta L = \frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\delta q + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\delta \dot{q} = 0.$$
   But, due to a "trick" to derive the Noether current discussed, for example, in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99853/50583), we also know that 
   $$ \delta S = \int j \frac{\partial \epsilon}{\partial t},$$
   where $j$ is the Noether current associated to the symmetry with constant $\epsilon$, which is just time translation, and indeed a symmetry because we have implicitly assumed that the Lagrangian does not explicitly depend on time. Therefore, $j$ is the Hamiltonian, and reparametrization invariance obviously forces $j=0$.

Comment: I don't find this answer very illuminating.  I don't see why we can't consider $\theta$ as a dynamical variable in the lagrangian formulation, since it's an arbitrary function of $s$ (or $\tau$).  How would you formulate the problem *without* introducing the hamiltonian and Lagrange multipliers directly into the action ?  Also, I suspect that the limits on the integral have something to say, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Cham: In both the Lagrangian and the Hamiltonian formulation, the space of dynamical variables is *fixed* for any given action - it's the space spanned by the $(q,\dot{q})$ and the $(q,p)$, respectively. The function $\tau(t)$ does *not* take values in that space and is therefore not a dynamical variable. One *can* introduce the time $t$ as a new variable on phase space, but then the intergration parameter of the action becomes something different, some parameter parametrizing a path in $(q,p)$ space with additional dimensions $(t,p_t)$.

Comment: Agreed.  Then I need to change the interpretation or the reasoning around equation (5) to get $H = 0$, but I don't know how.  I need to show an explicit (or implicit ?) assumption about *parametrization independence*.  This is the constraint that is associated with $H = 0$, and I want to get both of them at the lagrangian level, without introducing any Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: I'm not sure anymore about your last comment.  We could introduce a new lagrangian $\tilde{L}$ *defined* by (4), and consider $\theta$ as another dynamical variable ; $q^i$ where now $i = 1, 2, \dots, N, N + 1$ (so $q^{N+1} \equiv \theta$).  We have the $N + 1$'th canonical momentum $p_{\theta} = 0$ since this lagrangian doesn't have any $\theta^{\prime}$ in it.  The Hamiltonian is $\tilde{H} = \theta \, H$.  Euler-Lagrange applied to $\tilde{L}$ then gives $H = 0$.  I don't know how to interpret this.

Comment: @Cham Yes, you *could* do that. By making $\theta$ a new variable, you have effectively added the physical time variable as a new phase space variable. This usually leads to the new system being reparametrization invariant in the new integration parameter and hence the Hamiltonian vanishes on-shell; note for this that if $H$ is scalar, $\theta H$ transforms like a scalar density because $\theta$ is a derivative in the integration parameter $s$. I use that trick also in [this answer of mine](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/194925/50583).

Comment: But there's something missing that I don't understand in my trick.  What prevent me to do this for *any* Lagrangian, even $L = \frac{m \dot{q}^2}{2} - U(q)$, say ?  That wouldn't make any sense !  I don't see clearly the parametrization invariance here, unless we say something about the action itself, and its two limits : $t_1$ and $t_2$ changed to $s_1$ and $s_2$, etc.  I'm missing a piece to show that parametrization invariance implies $H = 0$.

Comment: @Cham I have edited the answer substantially.

Comment: Thanks.  Equation (d) is missing a tag.  Also, what would be the assumptions to make both systems equivalent ?  Parametrization invariance ?  If so, how does it appears ?

Comment: I think there's a mistake in the last equation (i.e. (d) ?).  It can be simplified on the left part and I'm getting this (two terms are canceling) : \begin{equation}\frac{d}{d s} \Big( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \, \dot{q}} \Big) - \theta \, \frac{\partial L}{\partial \, q} = 0, \end{equation} i.e the original E-L equation written as this  (see the change of parametrization ?): \begin{equation}\frac{1}{\theta} \, \frac{d}{d s} \Big( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \, \dot{q}} \Big) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial \, q} = 0. \end{equation} I think this is good.

Comment: @Cham: Indeed, there was a mistake. Still, the crucial point is that $q'/\theta = \dot{q}$ is an equation that is *external* to the Lagrangian systems under consideration and not part of the equations of motion, so you cannot use that equation in the course of showing the two systems are equivalent. Furthermore, I have added another section on how reparam. invariance implies $H=0$ from the Lagrangian viewpoint, since that seems what you seem to be ultimately after.

Comment: There's a misplaced equality sign in equation (d).  Should be an arrow instead.

Comment: I don't think we need to go to the Noether currents.  I suspect that the needed relation $q^{\prime} /\theta = \dot{q}$ is a way of imposing "parametrization invariance" to the system, but I'm still not sure.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: OP's trick makes sense in general. It is not necessarily related to relativity theory.

1. Let us first consider the Lagrangian formalism. It is natural to consider a general situation where the Lagrangian $L(t,q,v)$ is allowed to depend explicit on time $t$. Here the generalized velocities are $$v^j~:=~\frac{dq^j}{dt}.\tag{A}$$
   Define the Lagrangian momenta
   $$p_j(t,q,v)~:=~\frac{\partial L(t,q,v)}{\partial v^j}\tag{B}$$
   and Lagrangian energy function
   $$h(t,q,v)~:=~v^jp_j(t,q,v)- L(t,q,v).\tag{C}$$ It follows from the [EL equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)
   $$ \frac{dp_j}{dt}~\approx~\frac{\partial L}{\partial q^j}\tag{D}$$
   that on-shell
   $$\frac{dh}{dt}~\approx~-\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}.\tag{E}$$
2. It is natural to promote time $t$ (rather than OP's $\theta$) to a dynamical variable (alongside the generalized positions $q^j$) as a function of an arbirary worldline (WL) parameter $s$. The action $S[q]$ is promoted to
   $$\begin{align}\widetilde{S}[t,q]~=~&\int\! ds~\widetilde{L}(t,q,\dot{q}), \cr 
   \widetilde{L}(t,q,\dot{t},\dot{q})~:=~&\dot{t}L(t,q,\frac{\dot{q}}{\dot{t}}),\end{align} \tag{F}$$
   where dot denotes differentiation wrt. $s$. The action $\widetilde{S}[t,q]$ has a WL reparametrization gaugesymmetry
   $$ s\quad\longrightarrow\quad s^{\prime}~=~f(s).\tag{G}$$
   Define the Lagrangian momenta
   $$\widetilde{p}_t(t,q,\dot{t},\dot{q})~:=~\frac{\partial\widetilde{L}(t,q,\dot{t},\dot{q})}{\partial \dot{t}}~=~-h(t,q,\frac{\dot{q}}{\dot{t}}),\tag{H}$$
   $$\widetilde{p}_j(t,q,\dot{t},\dot{q})~:=~\frac{\partial\widetilde{L}(t,q,\dot{t},\dot{q})}{\partial \dot{q}^j}~=~p_j(t,q,\frac{\dot{q}}{\dot{t}}),\tag{I}$$
   and Lagrangian energy function
   $$\widetilde{h}~:=~\dot{t}^j\widetilde{p}_t+\dot{q}^j\widetilde{p}_j- \widetilde{L}~\equiv~0,\tag{J}$$
   which vanishes as expected. It represents a different (degenerate) notion of energy.

   The EL equations
   $$ \frac{\dot{p}_j}{\dot{t}}~\approx~\frac{\partial L}{\partial q^j}, \qquad  \frac{\dot{h}}{\dot{t}}~\approx~-\frac{\partial L}{\partial t},\tag{K} $$
   are not all independent. To solve them perhaps the simplest is to choose the static gauge $t=s$. To next generate the general solution use an arbitrary WL reparametrization (G).
3. Next let us consider the Hamiltonian formalism. Given an arbitrary Hamiltonian Lagrangian
   $$ L_H(t,q,p,v)~=~p_jv^j-H(t,q,p), \tag{L}$$
   the corresponding Hamiltonian action with WL reparametrization gaugesymmetry is$^1$
   $$\begin{align}\widetilde{S}_H[t,q,p_t,p,e]~=~&\int\! ds~\widetilde{L}_H(t,q,\dot{t},\dot{q},p_t,p,e), \cr 
   \widetilde{L}_H(t,q,\dot{t},\dot{q},p_t,p,e)~:=~&p_j\dot{q}^j+p_t\dot{t}-\widetilde{H}(t,q,p_t,p,e),\cr\widetilde{H}(t,q,p_t,p,e)~:=~&e(p_t+H(t,q,p)),
   \end{align} \tag{M}$$
   where the einbein field $e$ is a [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). The corresponding EL equations are
   $$\begin{align} \dot{q}^j~\approx~&e\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_j}, \cr -\dot{p}_j~\approx~&e\frac{\partial H}{\partial q^j}, \cr  \dot{t}~\approx~&e, \cr
   -\dot{p}_t~\approx~&e\frac{\partial H}{\partial t},\cr
   p_t+H~\approx~&0.\end{align}\tag{N} $$
   The Hamiltonian $\widetilde{H}$ vanishes on-shell as expected.

--

$^1$ The natural WL reparametrization covariant version of eq. (L) is
$$ p_j\dot{q}^j-\dot{t}H(t,q,p).\tag{O} $$
To obtain a Hamiltonian formulation, we should perform a (singular) Legendre transformation $\dot{t}\to p_t$. This yields a primary constraint. The Dirac-Bergmann analysis leads to eq. (M).
If we integrate out/eliminate firstly $e$ and secondly $p_t$ in eq. (M), then the Hamiltonian Lagrangian $\widetilde{L}_H$ reduces to eq. (O).