# Difference between the energy and the Hamiltonian in a specific example

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian, centrifugal-force

The problem is the following:

> Consider a particle of mass $m$ confined in a long and thin hollow pipe, which rotates in the $xy$ plane with constant angular velocity $\omega$. The rotation axis passes through one of the ends of the pipe.[image]
>
> The objective of the problem is to describe the motion of the particle.

My question is about the Lagrangian, Hamiltonian and energy of the particle.

Let $r$ be the distance of the particle from the $z$ axis. The kinetic energy $T$ is

$$T=  \dfrac{1}{2}m\dot{r}^2+\dfrac{1}{2}mr^2 \omega^2.$$

The potential is zero. So that, the Lagrangian is

$$L=T= \dfrac{1}{2}m\dot{r}^2+\dfrac{1}{2}mr^2 \omega^2.\tag{1}$$

We have that $\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}=p$ and $\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial q}=\dot{p}$. In this case,

$\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{r}}=m \dot{r}=p$ and $\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial r}=mr\omega^2=\dot{p}$.

The Hamiltonian is $\sum p\dot{q} -L$, so that

$$H=\dfrac{1}{2m}p^2 -\dfrac{1}{2}mr^2\omega^2\tag{2}.$$

According to *Laudau and Lifshitz-Mechanics*, the energy of a system $E$, when the Lagrangian have no explicit dependence on time (page 14), is

$$ E =\sum \dot{q} \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} -L=\sum \dot{q}p -L.\tag{3}$$

Applying this definition to our Lagrangian (1), we get that the energy is equal to the Hamiltonian

$$E=\dfrac{1}{2m}p^2 -\dfrac{1}{2}mr^2\omega^2=\dfrac{1}{2}m\dot{r}^2 -\dfrac{1}{2}mr^2\omega^2.  \tag{4}$$

But the kinetic energy of the system is just $T=\dfrac{1}{2}m\dot{r}^2+\dfrac{1}{2}mr^2 \omega^2$ and the potential is zero, so the energy should be

$$E=T=\dfrac{1}{2}m\dot{r}^2\color{red}{+}\dfrac{1}{2}mr^2 \omega^2\tag{5}$$

The middle sign is different from the sign of equation (4).

The questions are: Are my expressions right? Am I missing something? IS $L\&L$ definition of energy right?

Comment: There is a time dependent constraint force which leads to the different results. This example is discussed in section 1.6 of Goldstein's Classical Mechanics, 3ed.

Comment: You are right, but my question isn't about the equations of motion, but about the form of the energy and the Hamiltonian function, which is not discussed there.

Comment: In section 2.7 of the same book they discuss when the energy function matches the energy. One of the conditions is the kinetic energy being a homogeneous quadratic function of the generalized velocities. They assume this in the paragraph between equations 2.57 and 2.58, when they write $T = T_2$.

Answer (score 1):

OP's pipe-confined bead can be modelled in at least 2 ways using an initial frame:

1. As having 1 DOF $r$. This is OP's method. The Lagrangian is$^1$
   $$ L_1(r,\dot{r})~=~  \frac{1}{2}m( \dot{r}^2+r^2\omega^2), \tag{1L}$$
   the Lagrangian energy function is
   $$\begin{align}
   h_1(r,\dot{r})~:=~&\dot{r}\frac{\partial L_1(r,\dot{r})}{\partial\dot{r}}- L_1(r,\dot{r}) \cr
   ~=~& \frac{1}{2}m( \dot{r}^2\color{red}{-}r^2\omega^2),\end{align}\tag{1h}$$
   and the Hamiltonian is
   $$ H_1(r,p_r)~=~\frac{p_r^2}{2m}\color{red}{-}\frac{1}{2}mr^2\omega^2.\tag{1H}$$
   The Lagrangian $L_1$ has no explicit time dependence, so the Lagrangian energy function $h_1$ and Hamiltonian $H_1$ are conserved. The 2 latter functions $h_1$  and $H_1$ have the same value, but different from the total mechanical energy $E$ of the bead. As we shall see, the issue is that the bead is not an isolated system.
2. As having 2 DOF $(r,\phi)$ with 1 time-dependent [holonomic constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints) $\phi-\omega t\approx 0$. The Lagrangian is
   $$L_2~=~ \frac{1}{2}m( \dot{r}^2+r^2\dot{\phi}^2)+ \lambda(\phi-\omega t),\tag{2L}$$
   the Lagrangian energy function is
   $$h_2~=~ \frac{1}{2}m( \dot{r}^2\color{red}{+}r^2\dot{\phi}^2) -\lambda(\phi-\omega t),\tag{2h}$$
   and the Hamiltonian is
   $$ H_2~=~\frac{p_r^2}{2m}\color{red}{+}\frac{p_{\phi}^2}{2mr^2}  -\lambda(\phi-\omega t).\tag{2H}$$
   The 3 functions $L_2$, $h_2$ and $H_2$ have explicit time dependence. The Lagrangian energy function $h_2$ and Hamiltonian $H_2$ are equal to the total energy $E$.

   The [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)$^2$
   $$\lambda~\approx~\dot{p}_{\phi}, \qquad p_{\phi}~=~mr^2\dot{\phi},\tag{$\lambda$}$$
   can be determined from the EOM. It has an interpretation as an external constraint [generalized force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_forces) $Q_{\phi}=\lambda$ acting on the bead. Its power is equal to the rate of total energy gain
   of the bead $$ \frac{dh_2}{dt}~\approx~P~=~Q_{\phi}\dot{\phi}~=~\lambda\dot{\phi}~\approx~\frac{d(p_{\phi}\omega)}{dt}, \tag{P}$$
   i.e. the pipe is doing work on the bead. In other words, the difference
   $$ h_1~\approx~h_2-p_{\phi}\omega \tag{h}$$
   between the LHS and RHS of eq. (P) is conserved. This explains OP's observations.

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics;* section 1.6. (Hat tip: [secavara](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/178489/secavara).)
2. For a similar example, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37725/2451) Phys.SE post.

---

$^1$ The Lagrangian $L_1$ is the same in the pipe's rotating reference frame: the only difference is that the second kinetic term is reinterpreted as minus the centrifugal potential.

$^2$ The $\approx$ symbol means equality modulo EOMs & constraints.