# Definition of energy for a Lagrangian with constraints

Tags: energy, lagrangian-formalism, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, conventions

Suppose I have the Lagrangian in spherical coordinates:
$$\mathcal{L} = T=\frac{1}{2}m (\dot{r}^2 + r^2 \sin^2 \theta \dot{\phi}^2 + r^2 \dot{\theta}^2)$$
Where $T$ is the kinetic energy.
Now suppose the particle is constrained to move along a rotating hoop centered at the origin. The radius is fixed at $r=R,$ there is no friction, and there is a constant angular speed $\omega.$

Then the Lagrangian can be rewritten:
$$\mathcal{L} =\frac{1}{2}m(R^2 \omega^2 \sin^2 \theta + R^2 \dot{\theta}^2)$$
According to the definition of energy
$$E \equiv \sum_i \dot{q}_i \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}_i} - \mathcal{L}$$
The energy is now
$$\frac{1}{2}mR^2(\dot{\theta}^2 \color{red}{-}\omega^2 \sin^2 \theta)$$
*rather than*
$$\frac{1}{2}mR^2(\dot{\theta}^2 \color{red}{+}\omega^2 \sin^2 \theta)$$
Which of the above is the energy? Why is there a difference between the two?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37725/2451