# When does Hamiltonian equals to energy of the system?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

In classical mechanics, the Hamiltonian is well defined by the Lagrangian. Whereas, energy is a very ambiguous term. We just say $E=T+U$, and usually it equals to Hamiltonian. Does there exist a way that, by just looking at the Lagrangian mathematically, we immediately know the relationship between the Hamiltonian and the energy of the system?

And if we have a system, the Hamiltonian of which does not equal to energy, what is the physical meaning of that difference?

Comment: In what sense is energy ambiguous?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11905/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43135/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Intuitively I would say that the Hamiltonian is the energy of the system when the system is isolated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some technical conditions (on the type of constraints in your system) but operationally $H$ is the total energy when $\sum_i \dot q_i p_i$ is $2\times$ the kinetic energy.  Then clearly 
$$
H=\sum_i \dot q_i p_i-L=2T-(T-U)=T+U\, .
$$

If this is not the case, $H$ may be conserved but it's just not $E$. This occurs in a wide variety of systems, such as the flyball governor, and systems where some external agent maintains a constant rate of rotation (v.g. beads on rotating wires of various shapes.)   The dynamics is still constrained to remain on curves or surfaces of constant $H$, but there is usually no physical interpretation to this conserved quantity.

The simplest cases where $H$ *is* the energy are natural systems, for which the kinetic energy is quadratic in the velocities
$$
T=\sum_{ij} m_{ij}\dot q_i\dot q_j
$$
and there is no explicit time-dependence on $t$ in the Lagrangian.