# Conservation of Hamiltonian vs Conservation of Energy

Tags: energy, conservation-laws, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

What is the difference between conservation of the Hamiltonian and conservation of energy?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11905/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37725/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57985/2451 , and links therein.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the time derivative of the Hamiltonian

$$\frac{dH(q,p,t)}{dt}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}\dot{q}+\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}\dot{p}+\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}=-\dot{p}\dot{q}+\dot{q}\dot{p}+\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}$$

From this you see that the Hamiltonian is conserved if it does not depend on time,$t$, explicitly. $H$ may or may not be the total energy, if it is, this means the energy is conserved. But even if it isn't, $H$ is still a constant of motion.

Comment: But then my reference sheet says that the potential should be independent of velocity. How does that work?

Comment: The potential is velocity independent in order to have conservative forces. If $V=V(q,\dot{q})$, then the forces wouldn't be conservative and you couldn't state that $H=E$

Comment: So if a hamiltonian is not conserved, it is time dependent and its potential is velocity dependent?

Comment: In general yes. But you can have cases where only the Hamiltonian is a function of time OR the potential is a function of velocity. It's not necessarily that both cases should be true at the same time.

Comment: how would it look in quantum mechanics?