# Is it possible to formulate a Hamiltonian for a damped system?

Tags: energy, lagrangian-formalism, friction, hamiltonian-formalism, dissipation

I recently found out that it is possible to formulate a Hamiltonian for a system with time-dependent coordinates such that the Hamiltonian is not the same as the energy [When is the Hamiltonian of a system not equal to its total energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11905/) and that has me wondering if it is possible to formulate a Hamiltonian for a damped system under these conditions. I know that Hamilton's equations require that energy be conserved, but if the coordinates are time-dependent, would it still be possible to formulate and solve the problem?

I started trying to do it for a damped simple harmonic oscillator by starting with the Lagrangian for the system

$$L=e^{\gamma * t}*(\frac{mv^2}{2}-\frac{kx^2}{2}),$$

but I keep on coming up with a Hamiltonian that is just equal to the energy

$$H=e^{\gamma * t}*(\frac{mv^2}{2}+\frac{kx^2}{2}).$$

Comment: Uh...why do you want a Hamiltonian that is not the energy?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. I believe the Hamiltonian can be different from the energy if the coordinates are time-dependant. (see the link)

Comment: No, the hamiltonian is still equal to the energy, only the energy changes with time. A damped system loses energy to the surroundings.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147341/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Qmechanic, would you mind explaining what you mean by "The caveat is that the Hamiltonian (7) does not represent the traditional notion of total energy." in your "Unconventional approach"? I'm still a bit unclear how that is not the expression for total energy as a function of time.

Also, should the e(t) be in the numerator for both terms in your expression for the Hamiltonian?

Answer (score 0):

The following might help:

$H = \frac{1}{2}(mv^2 + kx^2) + \gamma mkvx$

decays exponentially with time along the solution of the damped system. Check by differentiating $H$ with respect to $t$ and using the equations of the system. So the "energy" $H$ decays exponentially instead of remaining constant.

Comment: Can you write down the equations of motion? I think you did your math wrong. Time independent Hamiltonians are always constant in time $ \dot{H} = \{ H, H \} = 0 $.

Comment: The system is damped, so their is no preserved quantity. The "Hamiltonian" i mentioned is not preserved as expected but it decays exponentially, probably the next best thing you would expect. $\overdot{H}= e^{-\gamma t}H$.

Comment: You aren't using Hamilton's equations correctly. You are forgetting that the third term gets differentiated for both equations. Hamiltonians are by construction constant in time.