# Does the Hamiltonian always represent the total energy of a system in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, hamiltonian

A simple question. In classical mechanics, the Hamiltonian is not always equal to the total energy of the system, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11905/2451) Phys.SE post. Is this also the case in quantum mechanics, or does something 'fix' it in this case?

Answer (score 2):

No, discrepancies between the Hamiltonian and the total energy in a quantum system is more or less taken over from the corresponding classical system.

*Examples:*

- The Hamiltonian in non-relativistic mechanics doesn't know about the relativistic rest energy $mc^2$ of the particles.
- The Hamiltonian relative to some local reference frame doesn't know about the total energy relative to some fiducial inertial frame, cf. e.g. section 8.2 in H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics.*

Comment: I'm not sure if thats the sort of 'not accounting for total energy' that I meant. I meant cases analogous to the famous forced oscillator problem in classical mechanics

Comment: Do you have some reference in mind? Which page?

Comment: Hmm maybe I just mean for driven systems?